# How to split a string, but also keep the delimiters?

Tags: java, regex

I have a multiline string which is delimited by a set of different delimiters:

```
(Text1)(DelimiterA)(Text2)(DelimiterC)(Text3)(DelimiterB)(Text4)
```

I can split this string into its parts, using `String.split`, but it seems that I can't get the actual string, which matched the delimiter regex.

In other words, this is what I get:

- `Text1`
- `Text2`
- `Text3`
- `Text4`

This is what I want

- `Text1`
- `DelimiterA`
- `Text2`
- `DelimiterC`
- `Text3`
- `DelimiterB`
- `Text4`

Is there any JDK way to split the string using a delimiter regex but also keep the delimiters?

Answer (score 456, accepted):

You can use lookahead and lookbehind, which are features of regular expressions.

```java
System.out.println(Arrays.toString("a;b;c;d".split("(?<=;)")));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString("a;b;c;d".split("(?=;)")));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString("a;b;c;d".split("((?<=;)|(?=;))")));
```

And you will get:

```
[a;, b;, c;, d]
[a, ;b, ;c, ;d]
[a, ;, b, ;, c, ;, d]
```

The last one is what you want.

`((?<=;)|(?=;))` equals to select an empty character before `;` or after `;`.

**EDIT:** Fabian Steeg's comments on readability is valid. Readability is always a problem with regular expressions. One thing I do to make regular expressions more readable is to create a variable, the name of which represents what the regular expression does. You can even put placeholders (e.g. `%1$s`) and use Java's `String.format` to replace the placeholders with the actual string you need to use; for example:

```java
static public final String WITH_DELIMITER = "((?<=%1$s)|(?=%1$s))";

public void someMethod() {
    final String[] aEach = "a;b;c;d".split(String.format(WITH_DELIMITER, ";"));
    ...
}
```

Comment: Nice to see there is a way to do this with String#split, though I wish there was a way to include the delimiters as there was for the StringTokenizer - `split(";", true)` would be so much more readable than `split("((?<=;)|(?=;))")`.

Comment: You have to use `%1$s` instead of `%1`.

Comment: Hahaha... DR, you are right. Lately I am doing a lot of RegEx in JavaScript so it is kind of mix up. :-p

Comment: That should be: `String.format(WITH_DELIMITER, ";");` as format is a static method.

Comment: One complication I just encountered is variable-length delimiters (say `[\\s,]+`) that you want to match completely. The required regexes get even longer, as you need additional negative look{ahead,behind}s to avoid matching them in the middle, eg. `(?<=[\\s,]+)(?![\\s,])|(?<![\\s,])(?=[\\s,]+)`.

Comment: First way is totally more readable, because you aren't mixing format tokens with regular expression tokens. Here is link to RE docs: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum

Comment: This won't work for delimiter pattern containing repeat, right?

Comment: I agree with justhalf; I got a "Look-behind group does not have an obvious maximum length" trying to use this with a regex representing all real numbers.

Comment: It sounds great, and I changed it as "((%1$s=>?)|(?=%1$s))", then worked as startwith.

Comment: what if I want split by two delimiters? let's say ';' or '.'

Comment: @NawaMan As per miracle-doh comment above; could you please update your answer with taking care multiple delimiters? I think you have shown example with only one delimiter (;) right? surprised how this answer solved the question? Or am i missing something ?

Comment: Hi miracle-doh and Kanagavelu Sugumar. You can use `(a|b)` to specify the delimiter. In this case, ';' or '.' would be `(;|\.)`. Notice that dot has to be escaped as it would mean to match everything.

Comment: It's great! However..., this seems not to be able to split by variable length regex. As @Chloe said, WITH_DELIMITER core body can not have full regex. JavaScript and Python can do, something like the right link [jsmime parse header](https://github.com/mozilla-comm/jsmime/blob/master/headerparser.js#L414). Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: Works great. What I didn't realized immediately, is, that you can specify multiple parameters just with `String.format (WITH_DELIMITER, "[\"?!., ]")` for example, to split sentences, handle the words (look them up in a dictionary for spell checking, for instance), and put the whole sentence together again. For just a single kind of delimiter, the whole question is not that relevant, or is it? You preserve the number of delimiters, well, that's interesting for CSV-files, for instance, of course. But that is solvable with the empty strings of just using `s.split (";")`.

Comment: Hi "user unknown", this will be useful when your delimiter is not just one str like for example (\r\n?|\n) for new line and you want save those too.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. I wanted to split a paragraph using space along with other delimiter and wanted the other delimiters to be treated as tokens too. The problem is other delimiters like , or . need not be separated from the word using space. LookAround happened to be what i precisely wanted.

Comment: One problem with this method:  empty tokens get discarded.  E.g. `System.out.println(Arrays.toString("a;b;;c;d".split("((?<=;)|(?=;))")));` produces `[a, ;, b, ;, ;, c, ;, d]`;  we want `[a, ;, b, ;, , ;, c, ;, d]` instead.

Answer (score 91):

You want to use lookarounds, and split on zero-width matches. Here are some examples:

```
public class SplitNDump {
    static void dump(String[] arr) {
        for (String s : arr) {
            System.out.format("[%s]", s);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        dump("1,234,567,890".split(","));
        // "[1][234][567][890]"
        dump("1,234,567,890".split("(?=,)"));   
        // "[1][,234][,567][,890]"
        dump("1,234,567,890".split("(?<=,)"));  
        // "[1,][234,][567,][890]"
        dump("1,234,567,890".split("(?<=,)|(?=,)"));
        // "[1][,][234][,][567][,][890]"

        dump(":a:bb::c:".split("(?=:)|(?<=:)"));
        // "[][:][a][:][bb][:][:][c][:]"
        dump(":a:bb::c:".split("(?=(?!^):)|(?<=:)"));
        // "[:][a][:][bb][:][:][c][:]"
        dump(":::a::::b  b::c:".split("(?=(?!^):)(?<!:)|(?!:)(?<=:)"));
        // "[:::][a][::::][b  b][::][c][:]"
        dump("a,bb:::c  d..e".split("(?!^)\\b"));
        // "[a][,][bb][:::][c][  ][d][..][e]"

        dump("ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException".split("(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])"));
        // "[Array][Index][Out][Of][Bounds][Exception]"
        dump("1234567890".split("(?<=\\G.{4})"));   
        // "[1234][5678][90]"

        // Split at the end of each run of letter
        dump("Boooyaaaah! Yippieeee!!".split("(?<=(?=(.)\\1(?!\\1))..)"));
        // "[Booo][yaaaa][h! Yipp][ieeee][!!]"
    }
}
```

And yes, that is triply-nested assertion there in the last pattern.

#### Related questions

- [Java split is eating my characters.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2819933/java-split-is-eating-my-characters/)
- [Can you use zero-width matching regex in String split?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2406633/can-you-use-zero-width-matching-regex-in-string-split)
- [How do I convert CamelCase into human-readable names in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559759/how-do-i-convert-camelcase-into-human-readable-names-in-java)
- [Backreferences in lookbehind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2734977/backreferences-in-lookbehind)

#### See also

- [regular-expressions.info/Lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Comment: Note that this will only work for relatively simple expressions; I got a "Look-behind group does not have an obvious maximum length" trying to use this with a regex representing all real numbers.

Comment: FYI: Merged from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/275768/is-there-a-way-to-split-strings-with-string-split-and-include-the-delimiters

Answer (score 38):

A very naive solution, that doesn't involve regex would be to perform a string replace on your delimiter along the lines of (assuming comma for delimiter):

```
string.replace(FullString, "," , "~,~")
```

Where you can replace tilda (~) with an appropriate unique delimiter.

Then if you do a split on your new delimiter then i believe you will get the desired result.

Comment: Only issue is that this doesn't work for a regex-based delimiter, i.e. `\d` for delimiting on digits.

Answer (score 26):

```
import java.util.regex.*;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class Splitter {
    private static final Pattern DEFAULT_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("\\s+");

    private Pattern pattern;
    private boolean keep_delimiters;

    public Splitter(Pattern pattern, boolean keep_delimiters) {
        this.pattern = pattern;
        this.keep_delimiters = keep_delimiters;
    }
    public Splitter(String pattern, boolean keep_delimiters) {
        this(Pattern.compile(pattern==null?"":pattern), keep_delimiters);
    }
    public Splitter(Pattern pattern) { this(pattern, true); }
    public Splitter(String pattern) { this(pattern, true); }
    public Splitter(boolean keep_delimiters) { this(DEFAULT_PATTERN, keep_delimiters); }
    public Splitter() { this(DEFAULT_PATTERN); }

    public String[] split(String text) {
        if (text == null) {
            text = "";
        }

        int last_match = 0;
        LinkedList<String> splitted = new LinkedList<String>();

        Matcher m = this.pattern.matcher(text);

        while (m.find()) {

            splitted.add(text.substring(last_match,m.start()));

            if (this.keep_delimiters) {
                splitted.add(m.group());
            }

            last_match = m.end();
        }

        splitted.add(text.substring(last_match));

        return splitted.toArray(new String[splitted.size()]);
    }

    public static void main(String[] argv) {
        if (argv.length != 2) {
            System.err.println("Syntax: java Splitter <pattern> <text>");
            return;
        }

        Pattern pattern = null;
        try {
            pattern = Pattern.compile(argv[0]);
        }
        catch (PatternSyntaxException e) {
            System.err.println(e);
            return;
        }

        Splitter splitter = new Splitter(pattern);

        String text = argv[1];
        int counter = 1;
        for (String part : splitter.split(text)) {
            System.out.printf("Part %d: \"%s\"\n", counter++, part);
        }
    }
}

/*
    Example:
    > java Splitter "\W+" "Hello World!"
    Part 1: "Hello"
    Part 2: " "
    Part 3: "World"
    Part 4: "!"
    Part 5: ""
*/
```

I don't really like the other way, where you get an empty element in front and back. A delimiter is usually not at the beginning or at the end of the string, thus you most often end up wasting two good array slots.

**Edit:** Fixed limit cases. Commented source with test cases can be found here: http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/6453

Comment: Wahoo... Thank you for participating! Interesting approach. I am not sure it can be help consistently (with that, sometimes there is a delimiter, sometimes there is not), but +1 for the effort. However, you still need to properly address the limit cases (empty or null values)

Comment: I invite you to properly reinforce this class, thoroughly document it, make a pass with findbugs and checkstyle, and then publish it on a snippets website (to avoid cluttering this page with tons of code)

Comment: You won the challenge ! Errr... congratulation! As you know, from the code-challenge thread, there would be no special points or badges for that... (sigh): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/172184. But thank you for this contribution.

Comment: @VonC Most of the time, throwing NPE on `null` argument is the correct way to go. Silently handling it leads to errors showing up later.

Comment: @maaartinus I agree, but surely there are instance where you want to throw a more user-friendly message than just NPE, right?

Comment: @hrzafer It is just there to be consistent. Most languages will keep empty string pieces at the end. `String.split()` in Java keeps empty pieces in the start and middle of the string, but not at the end.

Comment: FYI: Merged from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/275768/is-there-a-way-to-split-strings-with-string-split-and-include-the-delimiters

Answer (score 22):

Pass the 3rd aurgument as "true". It will return delimiters as well.

```
StringTokenizer(String str, String delimiters, true);
```

Comment: Note that its a legacy class and its use is discouraged in new code as per the comment in the class.

Answer (score 14):

I know this is a very-very old question and answer has also been accepted. But still I would like to submit a very simple answer to original question. Consider this code:

```
String str = "Hello-World:How\nAre You&doing";
inputs = str.split("(?!^)\\b");
for (int i=0; i<inputs.length; i++) {
   System.out.println("a[" + i + "] = \"" + inputs[i] + '"');
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
a[0] = "Hello"
a[1] = "-"
a[2] = "World"
a[3] = ":"
a[4] = "How"
a[5] = "
"
a[6] = "Are"
a[7] = " "
a[8] = "You"
a[9] = "&"
a[10] = "doing"
```

I am just using word boundary `\b` to delimit the words *except* when it is start of text.

Comment: +1 The best answer for me. but it doesn't work for alphanumeric delimiters in an alphanumeric string

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: Thanks for your upvote. Can you please provide a sample input where it didn't work.

Comment: for example this doesn't work for `abcdef` with `de` as delimiter, but you can solve the problem using `(?!^|$)(?:(?<=de)(?!de)|(?<!de)(?=de))`

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: Good point. However since OP started with this sentence `I'm trying to split a string with all non-alphanumeric characters as delimiters` therefore I provided this simple solution.

Comment: Note the first assertion to avoid an empty string in the result when the string ends with the delimiter, ie `(?!^|$)`

Comment: FYI: Merged from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/275768/is-there-a-way-to-split-strings-with-string-split-and-include-the-delimiters

Answer (score 13):

I got here late, but returning to the original question, why not just use lookarounds?

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\w)(?=\\W)|(?<=\\W)(?=\\w)");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(p.split("'ab','cd','eg'")));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(p.split("boo:and:foo")));
```

output:

```
[', ab, ',', cd, ',', eg, ']
[boo, :, and, :, foo]
```

EDIT: What you see above is what appears on the command line when I run that code, but I now see that it's a bit confusing.  It's difficult to keep track of which commas are part of the result and which were added by `Arrays.toString()`.  SO's syntax highlighting isn't helping either. In hopes of getting the highlighting to work *with* me instead of against me, here's how those arrays would look it I were declaring them in source code:

```
{ "'", "ab", "','", "cd", "','", "eg", "'" }
{ "boo", ":", "and", ":", "foo" }
```

I hope that's easier to read.  Thanks for the heads-up, @finnw.

Comment: I know it looks wrong--it looked wrong to me when I came back to it just now, a year after the fact.  The sample input was poorly chosen; I'll edit the post and try to clarify things.

Comment: FYI: Merged from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/275768/is-there-a-way-to-split-strings-with-string-split-and-include-the-delimiters

Answer (score 12):

I had a look at the above answers and honestly none of them I find satisfactory.  What you want to do is essentially mimic the Perl split functionality.  Why Java doesn't allow this and have a join() method somewhere is beyond me but I digress.  You don't even need a class for this really.  Its just a function.  Run this sample program:

Some of the earlier answers have excessive null-checking, which I recently wrote a response to a question here:

https://stackoverflow.com/users/18393/cletus

Anyway, the code:

```
public class Split {
    public static List<String> split(String s, String pattern) {
        assert s != null;
        assert pattern != null;
        return split(s, Pattern.compile(pattern));
    }

    public static List<String> split(String s, Pattern pattern) {
        assert s != null;
        assert pattern != null;
        Matcher m = pattern.matcher(s);
        List<String> ret = new ArrayList<String>();
        int start = 0;
        while (m.find()) {
            ret.add(s.substring(start, m.start()));
            ret.add(m.group());
            start = m.end();
        }
        ret.add(start >= s.length() ? "" : s.substring(start));
        return ret;
    }

    private static void testSplit(String s, String pattern) {
        System.out.printf("Splitting '%s' with pattern '%s'%n", s, pattern);
        List<String> tokens = split(s, pattern);
        System.out.printf("Found %d matches%n", tokens.size());
        int i = 0;
        for (String token : tokens) {
            System.out.printf("  %d/%d: '%s'%n", ++i, tokens.size(), token);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        testSplit("abcdefghij", "z"); // "abcdefghij"
        testSplit("abcdefghij", "f"); // "abcde", "f", "ghi"
        testSplit("abcdefghij", "j"); // "abcdefghi", "j", ""
        testSplit("abcdefghij", "a"); // "", "a", "bcdefghij"
        testSplit("abcdefghij", "[bdfh]"); // "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "ij"
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm confused: Java does have a split() method, which is modelled on Perl's, but much less powerful.  The problem here is that Java's split() provides no way to return the delimiters, which you can achieve in Perl by enclosing the regex in capturing parentheses.

Comment: FYI: Merged from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/275768/is-there-a-way-to-split-strings-with-string-split-and-include-the-delimiters

Answer (score 11):

Here is a simple clean implementation which is consistent with `Pattern#split` and works with variable length patterns, which look behind cannot support, and it is easier to use. It is similar to [the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/279549/5419712) provided by @cletus.

```
public static String[] split(CharSequence input, String pattern) {
    return split(input, Pattern.compile(pattern));
}

public static String[] split(CharSequence input, Pattern pattern) {
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
    int start = 0;
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    while (matcher.find()) {
        result.add(input.subSequence(start, matcher.start()).toString());
        result.add(matcher.group());
        start = matcher.end();
    }
    if (start != input.length()) result.add(input.subSequence(start, input.length()).toString());
    return result.toArray(new String[0]);
}
```

I don't do null checks here, `Pattern#split` doesn't, why should I. I don't like the `if` at the end but it is required for consistency with the `Pattern#split` . Otherwise I would unconditionally append, resulting in an empty string as the last element of the result if the input string ends with the pattern.

I convert to String[] for consistency with `Pattern#split`, I use `new String[0]` rather than `new String[result.size()]`, see [here](https://shipilev.net/blog/2016/arrays-wisdom-ancients/) for why.

Here are my tests:

```
@Test
public void splitsVariableLengthPattern() {
    String[] result = Split.split("/foo/$bar/bas", "\\$\\w+");
    Assert.assertArrayEquals(new String[] { "/foo/", "$bar", "/bas" }, result);
}

@Test
public void splitsEndingWithPattern() {
    String[] result = Split.split("/foo/$bar", "\\$\\w+");
    Assert.assertArrayEquals(new String[] { "/foo/", "$bar" }, result);
}

@Test
public void splitsStartingWithPattern() {
    String[] result = Split.split("$foo/bar", "\\$\\w+");
    Assert.assertArrayEquals(new String[] { "", "$foo", "/bar" }, result);
}

@Test
public void splitsNoMatchesPattern() {
    String[] result = Split.split("/foo/bar", "\\$\\w+");
    Assert.assertArrayEquals(new String[] { "/foo/bar" }, result);
}
```

Answer (score 9):

I like the idea of StringTokenizer because it is Enumerable.
But it is also obsolete, and replace by String.split which return a boring String[] (and does not includes the delimiters).

So I implemented a StringTokenizerEx which is an Iterable, and which takes a true regexp to split a string.

A true regexp means it is not a 'Character sequence' repeated to form the delimiter:
'o' will only match 'o', and split 'ooo' into three delimiter, with two empty string inside:

```
[o], '', [o], '', [o]
```

But the regexp o+ will return the expected result when splitting "aooob"

```
[], 'a', [ooo], 'b', []
```

To use this StringTokenizerEx:

```
final StringTokenizerEx aStringTokenizerEx = new StringTokenizerEx("boo:and:foo", "o+");
final String firstDelimiter = aStringTokenizerEx.getDelimiter();
for(String aString: aStringTokenizerEx )
{
    // uses the split String detected and memorized in 'aString'
    final nextDelimiter = aStringTokenizerEx.getDelimiter();
}
```

The code of this class is available at **[DZone Snippets](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/6450)**.

As usual for a [**code-challenge**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/172184) response (one self-contained class with test cases included), **copy-paste it** (in a 'src/test' directory) and **run it**. Its main() method illustrates the different usages.

---

Note: (late 2009 edit)

The article [Final Thoughts: Java Puzzler: Splitting Hairs](http://konigsberg.blogspot.com/2009/11/final-thoughts-java-puzzler-splitting.html) does a good work explaning the bizarre behavior in `String.split()`.
Josh Bloch even commented in response to that article:

> Yes, this is a pain. FWIW, it was done for a very good reason: compatibility with Perl.
>   The guy who did it is Mike "madbot" McCloskey, who now works with us at Google. Mike made sure that Java's regular expressions passed virtually every one of the 30K Perl regular expression tests (and ran faster).

The Google [**common-library Guava**](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) contains also a Splitter which is:

- simpler to use
- maintained by Google (and not by you)

So it may worth being checked out. From their [initial rough documentation  (pdf)](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/files/Guava_a_sketchy_overview.pdf):

> JDK has this:

```
String[] pieces = "foo.bar".split("\\.");
```

> It's fine to use this if you want exactly what it does:
>   - regular expression
>   - result as an array
>   - its way of handling empty pieces
>
> Mini-puzzler: ",a,,b,".split(",") returns...

```
(a) "", "a", "", "b", ""
(b) null, "a", null, "b", null
(c) "a", null, "b"
(d) "a", "b"
(e) None of the above
```

> Answer: (e) None of the above.

```
",a,,b,".split(",")
returns
"", "a", "", "b"
```

> Only trailing empties are skipped! (Who knows the workaround to prevent the skipping? It's a fun one...)
>
> In any case, our Splitter is simply more flexible: The default behavior is simplistic:

```
Splitter.on(',').split(" foo, ,bar, quux,")
--> [" foo", " ", "bar", " quux", ""]
```

> If you want extra features, ask for them!

```
Splitter.on(',')
.trimResults()
.omitEmptyStrings()
.split(" foo, ,bar, quux,")
--> ["foo", "bar", "quux"]
```

> Order of config methods doesn't matter -- during splitting, trimming happens before checking for empties.

Comment: FYI: Merged from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/275768/is-there-a-way-to-split-strings-with-string-split-and-include-the-delimiters

Answer (score 5):

I will post my working versions also(first is really similar to Markus).

```
public static String[] splitIncludeDelimeter(String regex, String text){
    List<String> list = new LinkedList<>();
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(text);

    int now, old = 0;
    while(matcher.find()){
        now = matcher.end();
        list.add(text.substring(old, now));
        old = now;
    }

    if(list.size() == 0)
        return new String[]{text};

    //adding rest of a text as last element
    String finalElement = text.substring(old);
    list.add(finalElement);

    return list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
}
```

And here is second solution and its round 50% faster than first one:

```
public static String[] splitIncludeDelimeter2(String regex, String text){
    List<String> list = new LinkedList<>();
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(text);

    StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
    while(matcher.find()){
        matcher.appendReplacement(stringBuffer, matcher.group());
        list.add(stringBuffer.toString());
        stringBuffer.setLength(0); //clear buffer
    }

    matcher.appendTail(stringBuffer); ///dodajemy reszte  ciagu
    list.add(stringBuffer.toString());

    return list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
}
```

Comment: These aren't doing what the OP asked for. `System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(splitIncludeDelimeter2(";", "a;b;c;d")));` prints `[a;, b;, c;, d]` but the desired output is `[a, ;, b, ;, c, ;, d]` instead.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it is possible with `String#split`, but you can use a `StringTokenizer`, though that won't allow you to define your delimiter as a regex, but only as a class of single-digit characters:

```
new StringTokenizer("Hello, world. Hi!", ",.!", true); // true for returnDelims
```

Comment: There I can't define a regex to specify my delimiters.

Comment: StringTokenizer only allows for single-character delimiters, though.

Answer (score 3):

If you can afford, use Java's replace(CharSequence target, CharSequence replacement) method and fill in another delimiter to split with.
Example:
I want to split the string "boo:and:foo" and keep ':' at its righthand String.

```
String str = "boo:and:foo";
str = str.replace(":","newdelimiter:");
String[] tokens = str.split("newdelimiter");
```

Important note: This only works if you have no further "newdelimiter" in your String! Thus, it is not a general solution. 
But if you know a CharSequence of which you can be sure that it will never appear in the String, this is a very simple solution.

Comment: FYI: Merged from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/275768/is-there-a-way-to-split-strings-with-string-split-and-include-the-delimiters

Answer (score 3):

Another candidate solution using a regex. Retains token order, correctly matches multiple tokens of the same type in a row. The downside is that the regex is kind of nasty.

```
package javaapplication2;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class JavaApplication2 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String num = "58.5+variable-+98*78/96+a/78.7-3443*12-3";

        // Terrifying regex:
        //  (a)|(b)|(c) match a or b or c
        // where
        //   (a) is one or more digits optionally followed by a decimal point
        //       followed by one or more digits: (\d+(\.\d+)?)
        //   (b) is one of the set + * / - occurring once: ([+*/-])
        //   (c) is a sequence of one or more lowercase latin letter: ([a-z]+)
        Pattern tokenPattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d+(\\.\\d+)?)|([+*/-])|([a-z]+)");
        Matcher tokenMatcher = tokenPattern.matcher(num);

        List<String> tokens = new ArrayList<>();

        while (!tokenMatcher.hitEnd()) {
            if (tokenMatcher.find()) {
                tokens.add(tokenMatcher.group());
            } else {
                // report error
                break;
            }
        }

        System.out.println(tokens);
    }
}
```

Sample output:

```
[58.5, +, variable, -, +, 98, *, 78, /, 96, +, a, /, 78.7, -, 3443, *, 12, -, 3]
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of an existing function in the Java API that does this (which is not to say it doesn't exist), but here's my own implementation (one or more delimiters will be returned as a single token; if you want each delimiter to be returned as a separate token, it will need a bit of adaptation):

```
static String[] splitWithDelimiters(String s) {
    if (s == null || s.length() == 0) {
        return new String[0];
    }
    LinkedList<String> result = new LinkedList<String>();
    StringBuilder sb = null;
    boolean wasLetterOrDigit = !Character.isLetterOrDigit(s.charAt(0));
    for (char c : s.toCharArray()) {
        if (Character.isLetterOrDigit(c) ^ wasLetterOrDigit) {
            if (sb != null) {
                result.add(sb.toString());
            }
            sb = new StringBuilder();
            wasLetterOrDigit = !wasLetterOrDigit;
        }
        sb.append(c);
    }
    result.add(sb.toString());
    return result.toArray(new String[0]);
}
```

Comment: FYI: Merged from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/275768/is-there-a-way-to-split-strings-with-string-split-and-include-the-delimiters

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using Pattern and Matcher, which will almost certainly achieve what you want. Your regular expression will need to be somewhat more complicated than what you are using in String.split.

Comment: +1, This is the right way. StringTokenizer will output delimiters if you place them in capture groups, but it's essentially deprecated. Using lookahead with split() is hacky for reasons that are outlined in the comments of the accepted answer -- mainly that it becomes a mess when there's more than one delimiter. But you can have a real tokenizer in a few lines with Pattern and Matcher.

Answer (score 1):

There is a new method [String.splitWithDelimiters()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#splitWithDelimiters(java.lang.String,int)) in Java 21:

```
/**
 * Splits this string around matches of the given regular expression
 * and returns both the strings and the matching delimiters.
 */
public String[] splitWithDelimiters(String regex, int limit)
```

Usage:

```
String s = "(Text1)(DelimiterA)(Text2)(DelimiterC)(Text3)(DelimiterB)(Text4)";
String[] array = s.splitWithDelimiters("\\((DelimiterA|DelimiterB|DelimiterC)\\)", 0);
Arrays.stream(array).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Prints:

```
(Text1)
(DelimiterA)
(Text2)
(DelimiterC)
(Text3)
(DelimiterB)
(Text4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Fast answer: use non physical bounds like \b to split. I will try and experiment to see if it works (used that in PHP and JS).

It is possible, and kind of work, but might split too much. Actually, it depends on the string you want to split and the result you need. Give more details, we will help you better.

Another way is to do your own split, capturing the delimiter (supposing it is variable) and adding it afterward to the result.

My quick test:

```
String str = "'ab','cd','eg'";
String[] stra = str.split("\\b");
for (String s : stra) System.out.print(s + "|");
System.out.println();
```

Result:

```
'|ab|','|cd|','|eg|'|
```

A bit too much... :-)

Comment: FYI: Merged from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/275768/is-there-a-way-to-split-strings-with-string-split-and-include-the-delimiters

Answer (score 0):

Tweaked [Pattern.split()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#split%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20int%29) to include matched pattern to the list

Added

```
// add match to the list
        matchList.add(input.subSequence(start, end).toString());
```

**Full source**

```
public static String[] inclusiveSplit(String input, String re, int limit) {
    int index = 0;
    boolean matchLimited = limit > 0;
    ArrayList<String> matchList = new ArrayList<String>();

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(re);
    Matcher m = pattern.matcher(input);

    // Add segments before each match found
    while (m.find()) {
        int end = m.end();
        if (!matchLimited || matchList.size() < limit - 1) {
            int start = m.start();
            String match = input.subSequence(index, start).toString();
            matchList.add(match);
            // add match to the list
            matchList.add(input.subSequence(start, end).toString());
            index = end;
        } else if (matchList.size() == limit - 1) { // last one
            String match = input.subSequence(index, input.length())
                    .toString();
            matchList.add(match);
            index = end;
        }
    }

    // If no match was found, return this
    if (index == 0)
        return new String[] { input.toString() };

    // Add remaining segment
    if (!matchLimited || matchList.size() < limit)
        matchList.add(input.subSequence(index, input.length()).toString());

    // Construct result
    int resultSize = matchList.size();
    if (limit == 0)
        while (resultSize > 0 && matchList.get(resultSize - 1).equals(""))
            resultSize--;
    String[] result = new String[resultSize];
    return matchList.subList(0, resultSize).toArray(result);
}
```

Comment: FYI: Merged from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/275768/is-there-a-way-to-split-strings-with-string-split-and-include-the-delimiters

Answer (score 0):

An extremely naive and inefficient solution which works nevertheless.Use split twice on the string and then concatenate the two arrays

```
String temp[]=str.split("\\W");
String temp2[]=str.split("\\w||\\s");
int i=0;
for(String string:temp)
System.out.println(string);
String temp3[]=new String[temp.length-1];
for(String string:temp2)
{
        System.out.println(string);
        if((string.equals("")!=true)&&(string.equals("\\s")!=true))
        {
                temp3[i]=string;
                i++;
        }
//      System.out.println(temp.length);
//      System.out.println(temp2.length);
}
System.out.println(temp3.length);
String[] temp4=new String[temp.length+temp3.length];
int j=0;
for(i=0;i<temp.length;i++)
{
        temp4[j]=temp[i];
        j=j+2;
}
j=1;
for(i=0;i<temp3.length;i++)
{
        temp4[j]=temp3[i];
        j+=2;
}
for(String s:temp4)
System.out.println(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a groovy version based on some of the code above, in case it helps.  It's short, anyway.  Conditionally includes the head and tail (if they are not empty). The last part is a demo/test case.

```
List splitWithTokens(str, pat) {
    def tokens=[]
    def lastMatch=0
    def m = str=~pat
    while (m.find()) {
      if (m.start() > 0) tokens << str[lastMatch..<m.start()]
      tokens << m.group()
      lastMatch=m.end()
    }
    if (lastMatch < str.length()) tokens << str[lastMatch..<str.length()]
    tokens
}

[['<html><head><title>this is the title</title></head>',/<[^>]+>/],
 ['before<html><head><title>this is the title</title></head>after',/<[^>]+>/]
].each { 
   println splitWithTokens(*it)
}
```

Comment: FYI: Merged from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/275768/is-there-a-way-to-split-strings-with-string-split-and-include-the-delimiters

Answer (score 0):

```
    String expression = "((A+B)*C-D)*E";
    expression = expression.replaceAll("\\+", "~+~");
    expression = expression.replaceAll("\\*", "~*~");
    expression = expression.replaceAll("-", "~-~");
    expression = expression.replaceAll("/+", "~/~");
    expression = expression.replaceAll("\\(", "~(~"); //also you can use [(] instead of \\(
    expression = expression.replaceAll("\\)", "~)~"); //also you can use [)] instead of \\)
    expression = expression.replaceAll("~~", "~");
    if(expression.startsWith("~")) {
        expression = expression.substring(1);
    }

    String[] expressionArray = expression.split("~");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(expressionArray));
```

Comment: With regexp this will be:
`Scanner scanner = new Scanner("((A+B)*C-D)*E");
    scanner.useDelimiter("((?<=[\\+\\*\\-\\/\\(\\)])|(?=[\\+\\*\\-\\/\\(\\)]))"); while (scanner.hasNext()) {
   System.out.print(" " + scanner.next());   
  }`

Answer (score 0):

One of the subtleties in this question involves the "leading delimiter" question: if you are going to have a combined array of tokens and delimiters you have to know whether it starts with a token or a delimiter.  You could of course just assume that a leading delim should be discarded but this seems an unjustified assumption.  You might also want to know whether you have a trailing delim or not.  This sets two boolean flags accordingly.

Written in Groovy but a Java version should be fairly obvious:

```
            String tokenRegex = /[\p{L}\p{N}]+/ // a String in Groovy, Unicode alphanumeric
            def finder = phraseForTokenising =~ tokenRegex
            // NB in Groovy the variable 'finder' is then of class java.util.regex.Matcher
            def finderIt = finder.iterator() // extra method added to Matcher by Groovy magic
            int start = 0
            boolean leadingDelim, trailingDelim
            def combinedTokensAndDelims = [] // create an array in Groovy

            while( finderIt.hasNext() )
            {
                def token = finderIt.next()
                int finderStart = finder.start()
                String delim = phraseForTokenising[ start  .. finderStart - 1 ]
                // Groovy: above gets slice of String/array
                if( start == 0 ) leadingDelim = finderStart != 0
                if( start > 0 || leadingDelim ) combinedTokensAndDelims << delim
                combinedTokensAndDelims << token // add element to end of array
                start = finder.end()
            }
            // start == 0 indicates no tokens found
            if( start > 0 ) {
                // finish by seeing whether there is a trailing delim
                trailingDelim = start < phraseForTokenising.length()
                if( trailingDelim ) combinedTokensAndDelims << phraseForTokenising[ start .. -1 ]

                println( "leading delim? $leadingDelim, trailing delim? $trailingDelim, combined array:\n $combinedTokensAndDelims" )

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want keep character then use split method with loophole in `.split()` method.

See this example:

```java
public class SplitExample {


    public static void main(String[] args) {  
        String str = "Javathomettt";  
        System.out.println("method 1");
        System.out.println("Returning words:");  
        String[] arr = str.split("t", 40);  
        for (String w : arr) {  
            System.out.println(w+"t");  
        }  
        System.out.println("Split array length: "+arr.length);  
        System.out.println("method 2");
        System.out.println(str.replaceAll("t", "\n"+"t"));
    }
```

Comment: here str.length is 12 , but in split method here i applied exceed  value index  to get this result

Comment: method 1
Returning words:
Javat
homet
t
t
t
Split array length: 5
method 2
Java
thome
t
t
t

Answer (score -2):

I don't know Java too well, but if you can't find a Split method that does that, I suggest you just make your own.

```
string[] mySplit(string s,string delimiter)
{
    string[] result = s.Split(delimiter);
    for(int i=0;i<result.Length-1;i++)
    {
        result[i] += delimiter; //this one would add the delimiter to each items end except the last item, 
                    //you can modify it however you want
    }
}
string[] res = mySplit(myString,myDelimiter);
```

Its not too elegant, but it'll do.

Comment: but what if you have multiple delimiters in a row?

Comment: FYI: Merged from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/275768/is-there-a-way-to-split-strings-with-string-split-and-include-the-delimiters