# Java: use scanner delimiter as token

Tags: java, regex, token, java.util.scanner, delimiter

I'm trying to find a good way to get a Scanner to use a given delimiter as a token. For example, I'd like to split up a piece of text into digit and non-digit chunks, so ideally I'd just set the delimiter to `\D` and set some flag like useDelimiterAsToken, but after briefly looking through the API I'm not coming up with anything. Right now I've had to resort to using combined lookaheads/lookbehinds for the delimiter, which is somewhat painful:

```
scanner.useDelimiter("((?<=\\d)(?=\\D)|(?<=\\D)(?=\\d))");
```

This looks for any transition from a digit to a non-digit or vice-versa. Is there a more sane way to do this?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206378/how-to-split-a-string-but-also-keep-the-delimiters, perhaps it helps.

Comment: the problem is that if I did the same thing for `\d` or `\d+` it will match at too many places

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: The edited question is so different, my original answer doesn't apply at all.  For the record, what you're doing *is* the ideal way to solve your problem, in my opinion.  Your delimiter is the zero-width boundary between a digit and a non-digit, and there's no more succinct way to express that than what you posted.

EDIT2: (In response to the question asked in the comment.)  You originally asked for an alternative to this regex:

```
"((?<=\\w)(?=[^\\w])|(?<=[^\\w])(?=\\w))"
```

That's almost exactly how `\b`, the word-boundary construct, works:

```
"(?<=\\w)(?!\\w)|(?<!\\w)(?=\\w)"
```

That is, a position that's either preceded by a word character and not followed by one, or followed by a word character and not preceded by one.  The difference is that `\b` can match at the beginning and end of the input.  You obviously didn't want that, so I added lookarounds to exclude those conditions:

```
"(?!^)\\b(?!$)"
```

It's just a more concise way to do what your regex did.  But then you changed the requirement to matching digit/non-digit boundaries, and there's no shorthand for that like `\b` for word/non-word boundaries.

Comment: I know, I was just suggesting a shorter regex to accomplish the same thing.  But you changed the requirements, so that's irrelevant now.

Comment: I'm still a little confused as to how your solution would have helped in the first case. It's the same problem now except with digits instead of words.. I just didn't want word boundaries to be an option, since I'm actually doing something a bit more complicated.