# String split() over white spaces and "(" and ")"

Tags: java, string, split

I have a `String`

```
String testString = "IN NEWYORK AND (OUT FLORIDA)" ;
```

I want to split out this string in array Like :

```
String testArray[] = testString.split("\\s()");
```

I would like the result to be:

```
testArray[0] = "IN";
testArray[1] = "NEWYORK";
testArray[2] = "AND";
testArray[3] = "(";
testArray[4] = "OUT";
testArray[5] = "FLORIDA";
testArray[6] = ")";
```

However, the output I get is:

```
testArray[0] = "IN";
testArray[1] = "NEWYORK";
testArray[2] = "AND";
testArray[3] = "(OUT";
testArray[4] = "FLORIDA)";
```

It is splitting on white spaces but not on "(" and ")" , I want "(" and ")" to be as seperate strings .

Comment: "_I want `(` and `)` to be as seperate strings_": `(` and `)` are separate strings in your array. But maybe I don't get your question.

Comment: nopes Baz actaual output is testArray[0] = "IN";
testArray[1] = "NEWYORK";
testArray[2] = "AND";
testArray[4] = "(OUT";
testArray[5] = "FLORIDA)";

Comment: Should that not be `\\s` instead of `//s`?

Comment: yes Jesper That i have corrected.

Comment: would this link be of any help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206378/how-to-split-a-string-but-also-keep-the-delimiters ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the below:

```
String testArray[] = testString.split("\\s|(?<=\\()|(?=\\))");
```

Answer (score 1):

split() requires a deleimeter to remove. Use StringTokenizer and instruct it to keep the delimiters.

```
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer("IN NEWYORK AND (OUT FLORIDA)", " ()", true);
    while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
        String t = st.nextToken();
        if (!t.trim().equals("")) {
            System.out.println(t);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String test = "IN NEWYORK AND (OUT FLORIDA)";
// this can for sure be done better, hope you get the idea
String a = test.replaceAll("(", "( ");
String b = a.replaceAll(")", " )";

String array[] = b.split("\\s");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it with string split, then monstrous regexes like `\s+|((?<=\()|(?=\())|((?<=\))|(?=\)))` are pretty much inevitable. This regex is based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206378/how-to-split-a-string-but-also-keep-the-delimiters) question, btw, and it almost works.

Easiest way is to either surround parentheses with spaces as suggested by @acerisara or use StringTokenizer as suggested by @user1030723

Comment: i think you have an extra ")" there . the correct one should be : \s+|((?<=\()|(?=\())|((?<=\)|(?=\))) . i used this website : http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ . however , for some reason it didn't match anything...

Comment: @androiddeveloper: you did not escape any of the parentheses and produced a malformed regex, that is why it didn't work.

Comment: what do you mean? i used exactly what you've written. also i don't understand if you agree about the extra ")" you had.

Comment: @androiddeveloper: what I mean is that in clauses like `(?<=()` the second '(' should be escaped as `(?<=\\()`. So, no, there are no extra parentheses in my regex :)

Comment: ok , so what should be written in the testing website in order to see that it works?

Comment: @androiddeveloper: for me, copying the regex as is works fine.

Comment: you are correct. maybe i didn't copy it well. sorry. however, for the sample of the first post , the last separated text is "(OUT FLORIDA)"

Comment: @androiddeveloper: yes, I couldn't manage to make it work for general case.