# Split string, put the elements into List with two possible delimiters

Tags: java, string, split, delimiter, splitter

I would like to split string into List on two possible delimeters "/" or "//". But what is more the delimeter should also be put into the same List. I can not do this with Splitter in Guava or java.util.Scanner.

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(str);
s.useDelimiter("//|/");
while (s.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(s.delimiter());
    System.out.println(s.next());
}
```

`s.delimiter()` returns `//|/`. I want to get `/` or `//`.

Do you know any other library which can do this?

I wrote some code, and it works but it is not very nice solution:

```
public static ArrayList<String> processString(String s) {
    ArrayList<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>();
    String word = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        if (s.charAt(i) == '/' && i < s.length() && s.charAt(i + 1) == '/') {
            if (!word.equals(""))
                stringList.add(word);
            stringList.add("//");
            word = "";
            i++;
        } else if (s.charAt(i) == '/') {
            if (!word.equals(""))
                stringList.add(word);
            stringList.add("/");
            word = "";
        }else{
            word = word + String.valueOf(s.charAt(i));
        }
    }
    stringList.add(word);
    return stringList;
}
```

On `"some/string//with/slash/or//two"` returns List with `some, /, string, //, with, /, slash, /, or, //, two`

On `"/some/string//with/slash/or//two"` returns List with `/, some, /, string, //, with, /, slash, /, or, //, two`

On `"//some/string//with/slash/or//two"` returns List with `//, some, /, string, //, with, /, slash, /, or, //, two`

Comment: Perhaps this has the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206378/how-to-split-a-string-but-also-keep-the-delimiters

Comment: Unfortunately this is not the same issue. In my case, the delimiter can be `/` or `//`. So this `System.out.println(Arrays.toString("a/b//c/d".split("((?<=//)|(?=//)|(?<=/)|(?=/))")));` doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `useDelimiter` method has a [signature](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#useDelimiter%28java.util.regex.Pattern%29) that takes a `Pattern` object, instead of a `String`.

You should use that one instead:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(str);
s.useDelimiter(Pattern.compile("/{1,2}"));
while (s.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(s.delimiter());
    System.out.println(s.next());
}
```

In order to capture the delimiter, you're going to need to change your approach.

```
Pattern p = new Pattern("(/{0,2})([^/]+)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
while(m.find()) {
   String token     = m.group(2);
   String delimiter = m.group(1); // (preceding delimiter. may be null)
   /*
    * ...
    */
}
```

Comment: `s.useDelimiter(Pattern.compile("/{1,2}"))` and `s.useDelimiter("//|/")` are doing the same. And I still can't see which delimiter was  used. `s.delimiter()` returns `/{1,2}`

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a good candidate to use regular expressions.  You can read more [about Java regular expressions here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/).