# Splitting String into Array of Strings Java

Tags: java, regex, arrays, string, split

I have a String that looks like this

```
The#red#studio#502#4
```

I need to split it into 3 different Strings in the array to be

```
s[0] = "The red studio"
s[1] = "502"
s[2] = "4"
```

The problem is the first one should have only words and the second and third should have only numbers...

I was trying to play with the `s.split()` Method, but no luck.

Comment: have you checked out javadocs for string.split() method ...

Comment: Have you tried StringTokenizer .http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html

Comment: You need to understand the specific rules governing the input data.  Is it _always_ `Some#text#with#words#number#number`?

Comment: Yes, it is always some text(unknown number of words) and then #number#number

Comment: What _exactly_ went wrong while using `s.split`?

Comment: [Lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookahead) mechanism might be useful in your case, although it will give you only split like `The#red#studio` `502` `4` so you will have to replace `#` in first part.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
String s= "The#red#studio#502#4";
String[] array = s.split("#(?=[0-9])");
for(String str : array)
{
  System.out.println(str.replace('#',' '));
}
```

Output:

```
The red studio  
502  
4
```

Ideone [link](http://ideone.com/UiOW9G).

Comment: Can you explain that regex?  Or at least tell us what that term is called so I can google it.  Thanks

Comment: I knew the keywords 'Lookahead' and 'Lookbehind'. Quick search gave me [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2206432/189608). Basically, I split when there is a hash character and look for a decimal but I don't split on it, but rather split only on `#`

Answer (score 1):

I've decided to edit out my impl because I think that @Srinivas's is more elegant.  I'm leaving the rest of my answer though because the tests are still useful.  It passes on @Srinivas's example too.

```
package com.sandbox;

import com.google.common.base.Joiner;
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;
import org.junit.Test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

public class SandboxTest {

    @Test
    public void testQuestionInput() {
        String[] s = makeResult("The#red#studio#502#4");
        assertEquals(s[0], "The red studio");
        assertEquals(s[1], "502");
        assertEquals(s[2], "4");
    }

    @Test
    public void testAdditionalRequirement() {
        String[] s = makeResult("The#red#studio#has#more#words#502#4");
        assertEquals(s[0], "The red studio has more words");
        assertEquals(s[1], "502");
        assertEquals(s[2], "4");
    }

    private String[] makeResult(String input) {
        // impl inside
    }
}
```

Comment: Can it be made more concise by only using `split`?

Comment: I don't know how, but it seems that you do.  Your example also passes my tests.

Answer (score 0):

Simply try: 
'String s[]= yourString.split("#")' it will return string array....