# java split regex: split string using any text between curly brackets and keep the delimiter

Tags: java, regex, split

I almost got what I need thanks to another [question on here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206378/how-to-split-a-string-but-also-keep-the-delimiters), but not quite.

I am trying to use java's String.split() to break up a string and keep the regex delimiter. My delimiter isn't a single char. Example:

`hello {world} this is {stack overflow} and this is my string`

needs to break into an array like:

`hello`

`{world}`

`this is`

`{stack overflow}`

`and this is my string`

I am able to match all text between { and } using `{[^}]+}` and split a string using it. But I really need to keep the text between { and } as well.

Comment: Is there any particular reason that you want to use `split` for this, rather than `find`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try maybe splitting this way

```
yourString.split("\\s(?=\\{)|(?<=\\})\\s")
```

It will split on every space that have `{` after it, or space that have `}` before it.

**[Demo](https://ideone.com/4ZE7oj)**

```
String text = "hello {world} this is {Stack Overflow} and this is my string";
String[] parts = text.split("\\s(?=\\{)|(?<=\\})\\s"); 

for (String part : parts)
    System.out.println(part);
```

output

```
hello
{world}
this is
{Stack Overflow}
and this is my string
```