# Loop through array inside array

Tags: java, for-loop, nested-loops

I have 2 Arrays: one contains words (`words_array`) and the other contains letters (`letters_array`)

I loop through the `words_array` and inside the loop I loop through the letters array 
and in the second loop I make a condition "if the word contain a letter in the letters array divide it by some way if else it should print the word as it is "
but it doesn't work because it prints duplicated words.

Here is my code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < words_array.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < letters_array.length ;j++ ) {
        if (arryWords[i].contains(letters[j]+"")) {
            int wordLength = arryWords[i].length();
            int letterIndex = arryWords[i].indexOf(letters[j]);
            String sub = arryWords[i].substring(0, letterIndex + 1);
            System.out.println(sub);
            System.out.println(arryWords[i].substring(letterIndex + 1, wordLength));
        } else if (!arryWords[i].contains(letters[j] + "")) {
            System.out.println(arryWords[j]);
        }
    } 
}
```

but the actual result is:

```
hello
hello
hello
he
llo
```

I want, if the word doesn't have any letters in the `letters_array`, it to print only one time and if the word has a letters in the `letters_array` it should divide two 2 part in the location of founded letter as I make in my code.

Thanks.

Comment: It would help if you told us how the expected result differs from the actual result.

Answer (score 0):

I renamed `letters_array` to `lettersArr` and `words_array` to `wordsArr` but I believe you want a [Set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) of String(s); for example,

```
// TreeSet would be ordered.
Set<String> wordSet = new HashSet<String>(); // The set of words.
for (int i = 0; i < wordsArr.length; i++) {
  final String word = wordsArr[i]; // local copy of the word.
  for (int j = 0; j < lettersArr.length; j++) {
    int pos = word.indexOf(lettersArr[j]); // get the position of the letter.
    if (pos > -1) { // if the word contains the letter.
      final String first = word.substring(0, pos)
          .trim();
      final String second = word.substring(
          pos + 1, word.length()).trim();
      if (first.length() > 0) {
        wordSet.add(first); // add before the letter.
      }
      if (second.length() > 0) {
        wordSet.add(second); // add after the letter.
      }
    } else {
      wordSet.add(word); // add the word.
    }
  }
}
System.out.println(wordSet); // display the result.
```

Comment: Thanks for help but your code made the same problem which is print the word one more time till divide it . as i shown in my first post

Answer (score 0):

The most concise way is to split the string by Regex:

```
public static void main(String... args){
    String[] word_array = {"blahXblahX", "blahYblahY", "blahZblahZ"};
    char[] letters_array = {'X','Z'};

    String pattern = "(?<=[" + new String(letters_array) + "])";
    for(int i=0; i<word_array.length; i++)
        for(String str: word_array[i].split(pattern))
            System.out.println(str);
}
```

### Output:

```
blahX
blahX
blahYblahY
blahZ
blahZ
```

### Explanation:

For this example `pattern` will have the form `(?<=[XZ])` which matches on the delimiters `X` and `Z` but [will not consume the delimiters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2206432/1290264). For example:

```
// consumes delimiter: ["blah","blah"]
"blahXblahX".split("[XZ]");

// keeps delimiter: ["blahX","blahX"]
"blahXblahX".split("(?<=[XZ])");
```

Comment: Thanks for help but i don't prefer regular expression in my code I cant handle it as exactly i want

Comment: Do you mean that the above code does not do what you want? Or that you don't know (and don't want to learn) regular expressions?

Comment: No my frind it helps me but it solve a small part in my case and i cant edit on it .