# Java spliting line into 2 lines by word

Tags: java, split

I am given this 2 lines where the second line has a tab right after 'a',

```
    a b C d
    a[tab]b c d
```

The result I want is:

```
First Line: "a", " bcd"
Second Line: "a", "[tab]b c d"
```

I have to use only one split function and I had tried `split("\\s+", 2)`, but it didn't work as expected.

Comment: "it didn't work as expected" doesn't tell us what it *did* do...

Comment: split("\\s+", 2) gives me this result:
First Line: "a", "bcd"
Second Line: "a", "b c d"

Comment: Mike, giving one example is not a sufficient definition of the problem. You have the explain how you want to split as well. As you can see from @BheshGurung there is easily more than one interpretation of this, which would yield different results for different examples, but the same result for this one.

Answer (score 3):

To keep the tab or space you need to use look-ahead, and split like this:

```
String[] split = input.split("(?=\\s+)", 2);
```

Complete demo:

```
List<String> inputs = Arrays.asList("a b C d", "a    b c d");
for (String input : inputs) {
    String[] split = input.split("(?=\\s+)", 2);
    for (String part : split) {
        System.out.format("Split string is '%s'%n", part);
    }
}
```

This prints:

```
Split string is 'a'
Split string is ' b C d'
Split string is 'a'
Split string is '    b c d'
```

Comment: @mike for more information, and general idea behind your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206378/how-to-split-a-string-but-also-keep-the-delimiters

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
String[] a = s.split("(?<=^\\w+)\\s+");
```

Answer (score -1):

You'll have to split using "\t" because \t is for a tab character. \s means any whitespace so it includes spaces.

Comment: Hi if I using "\t", I would get

> First Line: "abcd"

> Second Line: "a", "b c d"

Comment: He wants to split on either a space or a tab, `\s` would work just fine here.