# Formatting a string using Java

Tags: java, string

I have string which goes like this-

```
abc/def/ghi/jkl/mno/pqr
```

Now I want to represent this as-

```
abc/
def/
ghi/
jkl/
mno/
pqr
```

I am trying to achieve this using JAVA, can any one please provide me a sample code.

Comment: Yes we help, if you try something.

Comment: Try this.... "read Book" || "Google search" and then write code and i am sure u got your answer

Comment: Try regex. Refer this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206378/how-to-split-a-string-but-also-keep-the-delimiters

Comment: @SubirKumarSao You really don't need a regex for this...

Comment: Down-vote from me. I expect some effort from you before you post a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with:

```
String input = "abc/def/ghi/jkl/mno/pqr";
String[] output = input.split("/");

for (int i = 0; i < output.length; i++) {
  output[i] += "/";
}
```

Comment: You need not add the `/` explicitly. You can do with regex in split.

Answer (score 2):

One approach would be to replace each occurrence of "/" with "/\n" (\n is a new line character.)

String provides a [`replace()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) method for doing this.

Answer (score 1):

I'll hint you. Have a look at the [java docs for String class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) and find a method for replacing `/` with `/\n` in the string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code

```
String strValue="abc/def/ghi/jkl/mno/pqr";
String strValue1=strValue;

System.out.println("Actual Value \n >>>"+strValue);

strValue1=strValue1.replaceAll("/","/\n");

System.out.println("\nstrFormattedValue >>>\n"+strValue1);
```

The output of the program is as follows:-

```
Actual Value
 >>>abc/def/ghi/jkl/mno/pqr

strFormattedValue >>>
abc/
def/
ghi/
jkl/
mno/
pqr
Press any key to continue . . .
```