# Java: Split a string by special characters and spaces

Tags: java, regex, string

I am relatively new to java and I have to create a pig latin translator for a phrase. Here's the code I have right now so that I can split the phrase that the user would enter. Sorry for the improper formatting.

```
String english = "Queen of all reptiles";
String[] words = english.split ("\\s+"); 
for (int i = 0 ; i < words.length ; i++) {
    System.out.println (words [i]);
}
```

The output for this code is:

```
Queen   
of    
all   
reptiles
```

However, I would like to split the String english by spaces and special characters so that if

```
String english  = "Queen. of reptiles."
```

it would output:

```
Queen   
.   
of   
reptiles  
.
```

I attempted to do this: `String[] words = english.split ("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", "");` but it does not work.

Comment: Not sure why you would use such complex regex when you may use `Pattern` and `Matcher` with a regex like `(\\w+|\\.)` and find every `String` in your current `String` and add all the elements in a `List<String>` (more code verbosity but easier to maintain). Note: the *complex* regex was in an already deleted answer: `"(?:(?<!^|[^.]|)|(?=[.])|\\s+)"`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following for your string case.

```
String s  = "Queen. of reptiles.";
String[] parts = s.split("(?=\\.)|\\s+");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parts));
```

Output

```
[Queen, ., of, reptiles, .]
```

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a discussion of using split along with look-behinds to achieve this here:

[How to split a string, but also keep the delimiters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206378/how-to-split-a-string-but-also-keep-the-delimiters)

Answer (score 0):

As Luiggi Mendoza described in his comment, this will work as you described:

```
String english = "Queen. of reptiles.";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\w+|\\.");
Matcher m = p.matcher(english);

do {
   if (m.find()) {
      System.out.println(m.group());
   }
} while (!m.hitEnd());
```