# Android split TextView into strings

Tags: android, string, split, textview

i want to be able to split a TextView into a new string every time there is a @.

E.g. if TextView says " hello where are you @ i am @ school"

Output: string one = "@ i am "

String two = "@ school"

I have tried

```
String[] separated = text.getText().toString().split("@ · ");
tv.setText("first " + separated[0] + " next " +  separated[1] +  " next " +  separated[2] + " next " + separated[3]);
```

Comment: The split() method accepts only the delimiter, meaning that your should write `text.getText().toString.split("@")` to correctly split your string

Answer (score 5):

```
String input = "hello where are you @ i am @ school"
String[] split = input.split("@");

split[0] = hello where are you
split[1] =  i am 
split[2] =  school
```

If your question is more about including the @ symbol,
[How to split a string, but also keep the delimiters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206378/how-to-split-a-string-but-also-keep-the-delimiters)

Comment: i want to be able to do it automatically when the user input into an edittext