# Java Split with delimiter with dynamic value

Tags: java, android, regex, split

I need to split my text into pieces and also keep the delimiter as well, I know I can use below code to do that as explained [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206378/how-to-split-a-string-but-also-keep-the-delimiters):

```
Arrays.toString("a;b;c;d".split("((?<=;)|(?=;))"))
```

but what I'm stuck is that my text contains delimiter with a value inside it, my delimiter is **@[x]@**
where **x** is a value which can be **any number**. eg: @[1]@, @[44]@. What I want to achieve is to get an array as below:

```
text : "Hello my Name is blabla.@[1]@How are you today?@[2]@ByeBye"
```

and what I need to get:

```
[ "Hello my Name is blabla.", "@[1]@", "How are you today?", "@[2]@", "ByeBye" ]
```

How can I achieve that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following regex as a delimiter:

```
((?<=(@\\[\\d\\]@))|(?=(@\\[\\d\\]@)))
```

basically replacing the semi-colon with the expression `(@\\[\\d\\]@)` where `\d` matches any digit.

If more than one digit can exist, you can specify a range for the possible number of digits, for example `\d{1,1000}` instead of `\d` to have a maximum of 1000 digits. An unknown number of digits using an expression like `\d+` cannot be used with Java lookbehind regular expressions.

Comment: @Pshemo Thanks for correcting me! I completely missed that.

Comment: Sorry for bumping this up again but \d+ worked perfectly fine in my case, for example "blablabla.@[1]@blablabla@[27]@ worked like a charm.