# Split a string with multiple delimiters while keeping these delimiters

Tags: java, regex, string, split

Let's say we have a string:

```
String x = "a| b |c& d^ e|f";
```

What I want to obtain looks like this:

```
a
|
b
|
c 
& 
d
^
e
|
f
```

How can I achieve this by using `x.split(regex)`? Namely what is the regex?

I tried this link: [How to split a string, but also keep the delimiters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206378/how-to-split-a-string-but-also-keep-the-delimiters)

It gives a very good explanation on how to do it with one delimiter.
However, using and modifying that to fit multiple delimiters (lookahead and lookbehind mechanism) is not that obvious to someone who is not familiar with regex.

Comment: nice requirement doc....now you should move to implementation phase.

Comment: I refuse to answer this because it's a) likely a duplicate, b) possibly homework, and c) contains no effort

Comment: Please post your attempt.  And why don't you just split using a space as a delimiter?

Comment: never used regex before. I tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206378/how-to-split-a-string-but-also-keep-the-delimiters but I want to split a string with different delimiters

Comment: Start here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex for splitsplitting on optional spaces after a word boundary is

```
\\b\\s*
```

Note that `\\b` checks if the preceding character is a letter, or a digit or an underscore, and then matches any number of whitespace characters that the string will be split on.

Here is a sample [Java code on IDEONE](http://ideone.com/zn4ouw):

```
String str = "a| b |c& d^ e|f";
String regex = "\\b\\s*";
String[] spts = str.split(regex);
    for(int i =0; i < spts.length && i < 20; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(spts[i]);
    }
```

Comment: How about "x1 | x2^x3 &x4" and I wanna obtain ["x1", "|", "x2", "^", "x3", "&", "x4"]? thanks.

Comment: I think the best I can get for split is [`(?<=\\S\\d|[^\\w\\s])\\s*`](http://ideone.com/VINHjO)

Comment: emm, thanks, but it doesn't work on "x1 | yy & zz^xyz", which I want ["x1", "|", "yy", "&", "zz", "^", "xyz"]

Comment: I think I got it: you want to split on the word boundary and whitespace. Check [`\\b\\s`](http://ideone.com/nBD01b).

Comment: Well, close, but not exactly. My bad: I didn't make the problem clear. I want to split according to a specific set of delimiters, e.g. "|", "&", "^". So, given "x1 | xy & y1*y2 ^ xyz|zy+x", I want ["x1", "|", "xy", "&", "y1*y2", "^", "xyz", "|", "zy+x"].

Comment: How [about this solution](http://ideone.com/q0xCL7)? You will just have to trim all values in the array.

Comment: Excellent solution! Thank you. Should I edit the question and you edit the answer? I really like this solution.

Comment: Yes. I will when I am home.