# Extracting words from a pattern

Tags: java, regex

I have `String s = "#stack###over##flow".` How do I split `s` to have

```
String[] a = {"#", "stack", "###", "over", "##", "flow}
```

I tried `s.split("(?<=#)|(?=#)")` as in [How to split a string, but also keep the delimiters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206378/how-to-split-a-string-but-also-keep-the-delimiters) but it gives

```
String[] a = {"#", "stack", "#", "#", "#", "over", "#", "#", "flow}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The lookarounds need to be a little more assertive, meaning that the look-behind  needs to assert that the following position is either a word character or not a `#` and the lookahead needs to assert that the preceding position is either a word character or not a `#` as well.

You could use [word boundaries](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-boundaries.html#wordboundary) in each alternation:

```
String s = "#stack###over##flow";
String[] a = s.split("(?<=#\\b)|(?=\\b#)");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a)); //=> [#, stack, ###, over, ##, flow]
```

Or modify your lookaround assertions ( longer approach ):

```
String[] a = s.split("(?<=#(?!#))|(?<=[^#](?=#))");
```

Comment: Actually, you could have split it by `\b` (as done in the other answer)

Comment: @nhahtdh, Yes I actually realized that afterwards. Not enough caffeine yet.

Answer (score 2):

I think there is a much more nice way..

Looks insane:

```
\b
```

[Regex live here.](https://regex101.com/r/eF3vD2/1)