# How to split string with white spaces and include white spaces as elements in the result?multiple white spaces splitting

Tags: java, regex, string, split

The code I used to split the string with any number of white space is

```
String out="SELECT * FROM EMP WHERE EMPID=10";
String array[] = out.split("\\s+");
```

I want to include the white spaces in the "out" string into the array[] object while splitting with white spaces.
The output I want is:

```
array[]={"SELECT","[WHITE SPACE]","*","[WHITE SPACE]","FROM","[WHITE SPACE]","EMP","[WHITE SPACE]","WHERE","[WHITE SPACE]","EMPID=10"}
```

But the output what I am getting is:

```
 array[]={"SELECT","*","FROM","EMP","WHERE","EMPID=10"}
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split a string, but also keep the delimiters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206378/how-to-split-a-string-but-also-keep-the-delimiters)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to split it like this:

```
  String array[] = out.split("(?=\\s)",-1);
```

The code is:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    String out="SELECT * FROM EMP WHERE EMPID=10";
    String array[] = out.split("(?=\\s)",-1);

    for (String string : array) {       
    System.out.print(string);
    }
  }
```

Output:

```
SELECT * FROM EMP WHERE EMPID=10
```

Comment: if i want to split with ; and include the semicolon in the array list, can i use String array[] = out.split("(?=\;)",-1)

Comment: @zameer can you put me some input and expect output

Comment: I mean to say, How you split the string by referring white space with the help of out.split("(?=\\s)",-1).Now my question is how can i split the string with the help of semicolon (;). Can i use the above solution like String array[] = out.split("(?=\\;)",-1).

Comment: the above comment didn't fulfill by requirement, I am pasting the code.My requirement is i want to add the semicolon to the string when ever it is splitting the string but the semicolon is adding to next string ,here is the code  String sampleContent="hello ; hai ;  come fast ;";                                        String SQLScripts[] = sampleContent.split("(?=\\;)",-1); after looping in the for loop i am getting the out put as===>: OUTPUT: hello ,OUTPUT:  ; hai ,OUTPUT: ;  come fast ,OUTPUT:  ; But i want semicolon has to be added to the first splitting string only Like : hello; hai;

Comment: @zameer I used this:sampleContent.split("(?=\\s)",-1); and I hade this output : hello ; hai ; come fast ;===> if you want just : hello ; hai ;  give some time to do it

Comment: thank for your replay ,i am actually splitting wit semicolon not with the white space .i think you splitting with white space .String SQLScripts[] = sampleContent.split("(?=\\;)",-1);

Answer (score 5):

Since `split` accepts a regex, you can use [lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
out.split("(?<=\\s)|(?=\\s)");
```

This will output:

```
[SELECT,  , *,  , FROM,  , EMP,  , WHERE,  , EMPID=10]
```

Note that the delimiter (space in your case) is included in the result.

Answer (score 2):

**Try this one,**

```
String out="SELECT * FROM EMP WHERE EMPID=10";
    out = out.replaceAll("\\s+", ",[WHITE SPACE],");

    String [] array = out.split(",");

    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    for(String str : array){
        list.add(str);
    }
    System.out.println(list);
```

**output :** 
[image]

Comment: I don't think he literally meant to replace ` ` with `[WHITE SPACE]`. I guess he wants white space also as String in the output array.

Comment: then they have to submit it as a whitespace only, any way he can replace [WHITE SPACE] by " ".