# Java String to Array Splitting

Tags: java, split

I have a String, for example : `"My brother, John, is a handsome man."`

I would like to split this to an array such that the output is:

```
"My" , "brother", "," , "John", "," , "is", "a", "handsome", "man", "."
```

Can anyone help me with this? I need to do this on Java.

Comment: You can start with yourString.split(" "); Then you'll need a regex to separate the punctuation from the words. That should give you a starting point, see what you can find out for yourself

Comment: You have a good bunch of answers. If you want more, take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206378/how-to-split-a-string-but-also-keep-the-delimiters

Answer (score 5):

A combination of `replaceAll()` and `split()` should do it.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s ="My brother, John, is a handsome man.";
    s = s.replaceAll("(\\w+)([^\\s\\w]+)", "$1 $2");  // replace "word"+"punctuation" with "word" + <space> + "punctuation" 
    String[] arr = s.split("\\s+"); // split based on one or more spaces.
    for (String str : arr)
        System.out.println(str);
}
```

O/P :

```
My
brother
,
John
,
is
a
handsome
man
.
```

Comment: Can I check what does "$1 $2" mean?

Comment: @Nana - They are the values of *captured groups*. `(\\w+)([^\\s\\w]+)` -> has 2 groups. `$1` is first, `$2` is second.

Answer (score 0):

If you are considering only for `,` and `.` then an approach would be using `replace()` and `split()`

```
String x =  "My brother, John, is a handsome man.";
String[] s = x.replace(",", " ,").replace(".", " .").split("\\s+"); 

for (String str : s)
    System.out.print("\"" + str + "\"" + " ");
```

Output:

```
"My" "brother" "," "John" "," "is" "a" "handsome" "man" "."
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
    String string = "My brother, John, is a handsome man.";
    for (String s : string.split("\\s+|(?=[.,])"))
        System.out.println(s);
```

result is

```
My
brother
,
John
,
is
a
handsome
man
.
```