# How to split string to array where delimeter is also a token?

Tags: java, string, csv

How to split string to array where delimeter is also a token? For example, I have a string `"var1 * var2 + var3"` or `"var1*var2+var3"`, and I want to split this string with delimeter `"[\\+\\/\\+\\-]"` such a way that the result will be a such array:

```
{"var1 ", "*",  " var2 ", "+", " var3"}
```

(or `{"var1", "*",  "var2", "+", "var3"}`)

How can I do this?

Comment: @Tim except spaces should be preserved according to sample output

Comment: Regarding the above comment, I had commented earlier that the OP might be able to simply split on space, which apparently is not the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a delimiter that doesn't consume. Say hello to look-behinds and look-aheads, which assert but do not consume:

```
String array = str.split("(?<=[*+/-])|(?=[*+/-])");
```

The regex matches either immediately after, or immediately before, math operators.

Note also how you don't need to escape the math operators when inside a character class.

Answer (score 0):

Practically, your delimiter should be the space or the blanks:

```
string.split("(\\b)+")
```

This splits by blank spaces, so both the operators and variables end up in the resulting array.

Comment: Spaces should be preserved according to OP

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just split by blank space?

```
String splittedString = string.split(" ");
```

Also, same question here:

[How to split a string, but also keep the delimiters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206378/how-to-split-a-string-but-also-keep-the-delimiters)