# How to split a string, keeping only certain delimiters?

Tags: java, regex, split, regex-lookarounds

I have a question similar to [How to split a string, but also keep the delimiters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206378/how-to-split-a-string-but-also-keep-the-delimiters).  How would I split a String using a regex, keeping some types of delimiters, but not others?  Specifically, I want to keep the non-whitespace delimiters, but not the whitespace delimiters.

To make this concrete:

```
"a;b c"        | ["a", ";", "b", "c"]
"a; ; bb c ;d" | ["a", ";", ";", "bb", "c", ";", "d"]
```

Can this be done cleanly with a regex, and if so how?

Right now I'm working around this by splitting on the character to keep, and then again on the other one.  I can stick with this approach if the regex cannot do so, or cannot do so cleanly:

```
Arrays.stream(input.split("((?<=;)|(?=;))"))
        .flatMap(s -> Arrays.stream(s.split("\\s+")))
        .filter(s -> !s.isEmpty())
        .toArray(String[]::new); // In practice, I would generally use .collect(Collectors.toList()) instead
```

Answer (score 3):

I suggest to capture what you want instead of splitting using this simple pattern

```
([^; ]+|;)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/393)

Comment: While this doesn't answer the question asked about splitting on a regex, this may be the best answer to the underlying question of constructing the desired list of elements.  It's simple, concise, easy to understand, and self explanatory.  The other solutions require a fairly deep understanding of regexes, and a careful evaluation of the regex being used.  However, I'm not sure I should mark it as the accepted answer, as the actual question of splitting the list also has merit on its own.

Comment: This would be the actual Java code for this solution after updating it to include all whitespace that the \s character class includes, and not just spaces: `Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("([^; \t\n\u000B\f\r]+|;)").matcher(input); List<String> matches = new ArrayList<>(); while(matcher.find()) { matches.add(matcher.group()); } return matches;`. Note that the actual Java code for this is longer than using split since the API doesn't provide a one-line mechanism for getting all groups.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it this way:

```
System.out.println(String.join("-", "a; ; b c ;d".split("(?!\\G) *(?=;)|(?<=;) *| +")));
```

details:

```php
(?!\\G)  # not contiguous to a previous match and not at the start of the string
[ ]*     # optional spaces
(?=;)    # followed by a ;
|    # OR
(?<=;)   # preceded by a ;
[ ]*     # optional spaces
|    # OR
[ ]+     # several spaces
```

Feel free to change the literal space to `\\s`. To avoid an empty item *(at the beginning of the resulting array when the string starts with a whitespace)*, you need to trim the string first.

Obviously, without the constraint of splitting, @alphabravo way is the most simple.

Comment: This is great, but won't `"(?!\\G)\\s*"` alone do the trick?  It certainly works for the examples given.

Comment: @AlanMoore I updated the examples to show that I expect multiple contiguous non-whitespace, non-semicolon characters to be included in the same match result.  This simplification will not work for the updated example.

Answer (score 2):

I found a regex that works:

```
(\\s+)|((?<=;)(?=\\S)|(?<=\\S)(?=;))
```

```
public static void main(String argss[]){
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString("a; ; b c ;d"
        .split("(\\s+)|((?<=;)(?=\\S)|(?<=\\S)(?=;))")));
}
```

Will print out:

```
[a, ;, ;, b, c, ;, d]
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to split on whitespace, or between a letter and a non letter:

```
str.split("\\s+|(?<=\\w)(?=\\W)|(?<=\\W)(?=\\w)");
```

Comment: This doesn't quite answer the question as posed, since I don't actually care if it's a word character (\w being the same as [\p{Alpha}\p{gc=Mn}\p{gc=Me}\p{gc=Mc}\p{Digit}\p{gc=Pc}]), so much as whether it's a semicolon or not.  Arthur 's solution above (http://stackoverflow.com/a/39059565/1108305) is effectively the same as this one, but only checks semicolons and whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

After realizing Java doesn't support adding captured split char's to the
split array elements, thought I'd try a *split* solution without that
capability.

Basically there are only 4 permutations involving whitespace and the colon.
Finally, there is just the whitespace.

Here is the regex.

Raw:  `\s+(?=;)|(?<=;)\s+|(?<!\s)(?=;)|(?<=;)(?!\s)|\s+`

Stringed:  `"\\s+(?=;)|(?<=;)\\s+|(?<!\\s)(?=;)|(?<=;)(?!\\s)|\\s+"`

And the expanded regex with permutation's explained.
Good luck!

```
    \s+                  # Required, suck up wsp before ;
    (?= ; )              # ;

 |                     # or,

    (?<= ; )             # ;
    \s+                  # Required, suck up wsp after ;

 |                     # or,

    (?<! \s )            # No wsp before ;
    (?= ; )              # ;

 |                     # or,

    (?<= ; )             # ;
    (?! \s )             # No wsp after ;

 |                     # or,

    \s+                  # Required wsp
```

**Edit**

To stop a split on whitespace at BOS, use this regex.

Raw:  `\s+(?=;)|(?<=;)\s+|(?<!\s)(?=;)|(?<=;)(?!\s)|(?<!^)(?<!\s)\s+`

Stringed:  `"\\s+(?=;)|(?<=;)\\s+|(?<!\\s)(?=;)|(?<=;)(?!\\s)|(?<!^)(?<!\\s)\\s+"`

Explained:

```
    \s+                  # Required, suck up wsp before ;
    (?= ; )              # ;

 |                     # or,

    (?<= ; )             # ;
    \s+                  # Required, suck up wsp after ;

 |                     # or,

    (?<! \s )            # No wsp before ;
    (?= ; )              # ;

 |                     # or,

    (?<= ; )             # ;
    (?! \s )             # No wsp after ;

 |                     # or,

    (?<! ^ )             # No split of wsp at BOS   
    (?<! \s )
    \s+                  # Required wsp
```

Comment: This almost works, but it includes initial spaces as an additional split (" a " -> ["", "a"] instead of ["a"]).

Comment: If you want to allow those additional spaces, just needs an assertion.[

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're saying.  When I apply your regex using String.split() in Java to "  a  ", it gives two elements in the split list (the empty string and "a").  I would want and expect it to return just one ("a").

Comment: I'll put up an edit for you, just a second. Split won't let you trim inline, but you can match the " a" as one element, then do a trim left on element 0. That something you can do ?

Comment: Actually, I think I was misunderstanding how Java splits Strings; trailing empty Strings are excluded, but not leading ones.

Comment: Ok, I've added a regex to disallow wsp split at BOS. But, this will make `" a;b" -> [" a", "b"]`, but you should be able to do a blind trim of element 0. The best that can be done with regex and split.

Comment: — Now that I realize that it's a quirk in the Java split API, I don't think there's value in working around the issue in the regex itself.  I think either trimming the string first, or using a third-party splitting API (such as Guava's [Splitter](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/StringsExplained#Splitter) would be the better approach.

Comment: I wouldn't use any 3rd party for this. The best approach is to first run global replace `^\s+|\s+$` with blank. Then use my first regex with split.

Answer (score 0):

Borrowing @CasimiretHippolyte `\G` trick you may want to split on

```
\\s+|(?!\\G)()
```

Note: no delimiters are specified.

#### Update

Based on avoiding split on very first spaces:

```
(?m)(?<!^|\\s)(\\s+|)(?!$)
```

Comment: Why the empty capturing group "()" at the end?  It seems to not be doing anything, and it appears to work just as correctly without it.

Comment: Yes capturing group is for verbosity only. Also I updated my answer to fit your new requirement. Please check. @M.Justin