# Java Regex split string between delimiter and keep delimiter

Tags: java, arrays, regex, string

I have a java string that looks like this;

```
(fname:jon)(lname:doe)(guaranteer: Sam (W) Willis)(age:35)(addr:1 Turnpike Plaza)(favcolor:blue)
```

And I want to split this String from delimiter `(fname:jon)<here>(lname:doe)`.

I tried splitting through regex `\)\(` but it just breaks my code

```
arr = s.split("\\)\\(");
for (String a: arr) System.out.println(a);
```

Output

```
(fname:jon
lname:doe
guaranteer: Sam (W) Willis
age:35
addr:1 Turnpike Plaza
favcolor:blue)
```

I also looked at this question: [How to split a string, but also keep the delimiters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206378/), but it didn't helped because in my case, I want to keep the delimiter `)(` and split delimiter evenly as well, i.e., the first bracket should go to first result and second to second result.

The regex that i used was `s.split("(?<=\\)\\()")` and it gave output:

```
(fname:jon)(
lname:doe)(
guaranteer: Sam (W) Willis)(
age:35)(
addr:1 Turnpike Plaza)(
favcolor:blue)
```

This is my desired output:

```
(fname:jon)
(lname:doe)
(guaranteer: Sam (W) Willis)
(age:35)
(addr:1 Turnpike Plaza)
(favcolor:blue)
```

Comment: Try `(?<=\\))(?=\\()`

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew I've specifically pointed out why that answer doesn't helps in my case. Can you tell me why is this duplicate?

Comment: The answer that generalizes all those cases is http://stackoverflow.com/a/2848147/3832970. The third from the bottom is your case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can split your string using positive lookahead and positive lookbehind like this:

RegEx `(?<=\))(?=\()`

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/rYseSW/2)

1. `(?<=\))` positive lookbehind which indicates that closing bracket should preceed the split position.
2. `(?=\()` positive lookahead which indicates that opening bracket should follow that split position.

**Output**

```
(fname:jon)
(lname:doe)
(guaranteer: Sam (W) Willis)
(age:35)
(addr:1 Turnpike Plaza)
(favcolor:blue)
```

**Code**

```
String s = "(fname:jon)(lname:doe)(guaranteer: Sam (W) Willis)(age:35)(addr:1 Turnpike Plaza)(favcolor:blue)";
String arr[] = s.split("(?<=\\))(?=\\()");
for (String a: arr) System.out.println(a);
```

Comment: Delete the pointless `.{0}` - it has no effect whatever, And you are incorrect: There is no "null" character matched here, the null char is `'\0'`. The match is *between* characters based on the look arounds, which is nothing particularly special.

Comment: @Bohemian I originally kept `.{0}` just to indicate that *this is the delimiter*. By null I actually meant *the empty position between positive lookahead and positive lookbehind*. However, thanks for pointing it out, I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: You haven't really update all your post, particularly the first sentence

Comment: @Bohemian updated.

Answer (score 7):

You can use a *positive lookbehind* and *negative lookahead* to achieve this :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String s = "(fname:jon)(lname:doe)(guaranteer: Sam (W) Willis)(age:35)"
            + "(addr:1 Turnpike Plaza)(favcolor:blue)";
    String[] arr = s.split("(?<=\\)(?!\\s))"); // positive lookbehind for ")" and negative lookahead for "space"
    for (String str : arr) {
        System.out.println(str);
    }

}
```

O/P :

```
(fname:jon)
(lname:doe)
(guaranteer: Sam (W) Willis)
(age:35)
(addr:1 Turnpike Plaza)
(favcolor:blue)
```