# How to parse x+y so that I get x, +, y (an array) in Java?

Tags: java, regex

```
String s = " x  +  y  ";
String[] sArr = s.split("\\s*-|+|*|/\\s*");
```

I have a String such as: `"  x   +  y  "` I want to get an array with elements: `x, +, y` (no whitespaces) Instead of `+`, if I use `-,/,*` they should also work. I was trying something like the above code, but this gives errors because of `+` and/or `*`. It takes them as part of the regular expression.

How can I make this work? Please help.

Comment: Have you tried just splitting on white spaces?  `s.split("\\s*")`.  The argument to split tells you what should come _between_ the elements you want to keep.  Since you want to keep the `+`, it shouldn't be part of the `split` regex unless you're doing something really tricky.

Comment: `s.replaceAll("\\s","").split("")`

Answer (score 1):

```
String s = " x  +  y  ";
String[] sArr = s.trim().split("\\s+"); 
System.out.println(sArr[0]+":"+sArr[1]+":"+sArr[2]);
```

Output: `x:+:y`

Comment: you code will not work if input string doesn't contain space in between.

Comment: There should be some separator to separate one word from another. In this question OP is clearly asking to to separate by space. Otherwise how do you separate a String like " x + 25 + 50 " if you don't know what is the separator ?

Comment: yes, OP probably wants to separate the string using the operator sign.

Answer (score 1):

```
String s = " x  +  y - z / x * y ";
s = s.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
```

1st alternative:

```
String[] sArr = s.split("((?<=[\\+\\-\\*/])|(?=[\\+\\-\\*/]))");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sArr));
```

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2206432/5352399

2nd alternative:

```
String[] sArr = s.split("\\s*");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sArr));
```

In both cases, output:

```
[x, +, y, -, z, /, x, *, y]
```

If you don't want the operators in the output, you can do something like this.

```
String[] sArr = s.split("\\s*[-,+,*,/]\\s*");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sArr));
```

Output:

```
[x, y, z, x, y]
```