# Creating Substrings in a while loop

Tags: java, substring

I am trying to create a method that `substrings` a `string` from the occurrence from one word(labelA) to another(labelB) and vice versa.

If the string is `The Number2 quick Number1 onyx goblin jumps Number1  over the lazy dwarf Number2`

I am trying to get the strings which are between labels to be assigned to Sub variable.

So it outputs vector will have value similar to this in each run of while loop

```
temp.addElement("Number2");
temp.add("The");
```

Then

```
temp.addElement("Number1");
temp.add("quick ");
```

Then

```
temp.addElement("Number1");
temp.add("onyx goblin jumps  ");
```

Then

```
temp.addElement("Number2");
temp.add("over the lazy dwarf  ");
```

This is what I have tried

```
 private Vector cutter(String str){
    Vector thisPlan - new Vector();
    Vector temp = new Vector();
    try{
       int i =0;
       int end = 0;
       String labelA = "Number1:";
       String labelB = "Number2:";
       String Sub = "";
       int pos = 0;
       while(i<r.length()){
         try{
             pos = str.indexOf(labelA, pos);
             Sub = str.substring(pos,str.length());
             pos++;
         }catch(Exception e){
             pos = str.indexOf)(labelB, pos);
             Sub = str.substring(pos,str.length());
              pos++;
         }
         if(!labelA.equals(labelB) || (labelA.equals(labelB) && !StringUtil.scrub(Sub).equals(""))){
          temp.addElement(labelA);
          temp.add(Sub);
         }
         if(!labelA.equals(labelB) || (labelA.equals(labelB) && !StringUtil.scrub(Sub).equals(""))){
           temp.addElement(labelB);
           temp.add(Sub);
          }
          temp = new Vector();
      } catch (Exception e){
       }
      return thisPlan;
    }
}
```

Please help, and at least give suggestion how can I accomplish this.

Comment: What's the problem with your code?

Comment: Its not working just catches exception.

Comment: Show your error log .

Comment: Unfortunately I dont have it, thats another problem. But I am looking for suggestion

Comment: Remove the `catch (Exception e)` block then - you'll get a nice stack trace that tells you exactly what's wrong.

Comment: A suggestion: don't use `try.. catch` and do nothing in the `catch` block, or not printing the stack trace without a good reason. Otherwise, you won't know what's wrong with your program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`String.split(String)` will I believe do the trick:

```
"The Number2 quick Number1 onyx goblin jumps Number1 over the lazy dwarf Number2 ")
    .split("Number2|Number1")
```

equals

```
["The ", " quick ", " onyx goblin jumps ", " over the lazy dwarf ", " "]
```

which looks a lot like what I believe you are seeking.

To also keep the separating `"Number1"` and `"Number2"` delimiting strings you can use [zero-width positive lookahead and lookbehind expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) as used in https://stackoverflow.com/a/19951885/1840078 and [How to split a string, but also keep the delimiters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206378/how-to-split-a-string-but-also-keep-the-delimiters?noredirect=1&lq=1):

```
"The Number2 quick Number1 onyx goblin jumps Number1 over the lazy dwarf Number2 "
    .split("(?=Number[12])|(?<=Number[12])")
```

equals

```
["The ", "Number2", " quick ", "Number1", " onyx goblin jumps ",
    "Number1", " over the lazy dwarf ", "Number2", " "]
```

Comment: Yeah can you please elaborate

Comment: Thanks alot got it

Comment: You're welcome! I was just about to add some `String[]` to `Vector` conversion code in a `private Vector cutter(String str)` method to my answer. Glad you were able to get there yourself. :)

Comment: How can I print the the Label which occured before the substring

Comment: As that will be needed to put in vector too like Number1 or Number2

Comment: Storing both labels and in-between texts in a single `Vector` would be a bit different problem with moderately different solution code. If you could you post that as a separate question I'd be happy to answer there.

Comment: In brief I'd probably use `Pattern` and `Matcher` with a more complex regex to meet the 'also store labels' need. More specifically I'd leverage either `Matcher.find()` or `Matcher.group(int)` depending which pattern best suits your needs. I could say more in an Answer to that Question. :)