# How Split a string in Java

Tags: java

I have a string which is (30) can someone please help me to split it as below

1. (
2. 32
3. )

My concern is there is no spaces between the brackets and number.
After splitting I wants to store each and every character to separate variable and I want to convert "32" in to integer value to use it

Comment: So you want to split at every bracket-number boundary?

Comment: you want to split 32 into 30...?

Comment: We do not do your work. Add what you have tried.

Comment: @jens i am not expecting u to do my work, i am not an expert so that i have raised a question

Comment: Part of a question should be an attempt to solve your Problem. Read [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try as follows use `toCharArray()`

```
String str = "(32)";

char[] chars = str.toCharArray();

System.out.println(chars[0]);
System.out.println(chars[1]);
System.out.println(chars[2]);
System.out.println(chars[3]);
```

Comment: may i know in detail please. as i am not an expert in java basically i am a tester and implementing automation

Comment: After splitting can i store each character in to any other variable

Comment: @NarendraChetan when you use toCharArray your String seperate to it's character level and store in char array.

Comment: @NarendraChetan yes you can use as follows char a = chars[0] like wise

Comment: it works for me thanks a lot. I appreciate your support and timely help

Answer (score 1):

One option uses lookarounds to determine where the split should take place.  Assuming that you want a split to happen at the boundary between a word a non word character, lookarounds would work because they assert but do not consume, leaving all the input to appear in the result.

```
String input = "(32)";
String[] parts = input.split("(?<=[^A-Za-z0-9])(?=[A-Za-z0-9])|(?<=[A-Za-z0-9])(?=[^A-Za-z0-9])");
for (String part : parts) {
    System.out.println(part);
}

(
32
)
```

### Demo

Comment: I didn't get u please help me in detail

Comment: @NarendraChetan Your question has been closed because it is unclear what you are asking.  Edit your question and tell us the logic by which your input gets split the way that it does.  My answer is correct, under certain assumptions.

Answer (score 1):

Regex pattern "\\b" is used match word separated by delimiter.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main( String[] str ) {

        String[] split = splitStr( "(32)" );
        for ( String s : split ) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }

    public static String[] splitStr( String str ) {
        String regex = "\\b";
        return str.split(regex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do not add Code without explanation. It is not helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to keep the split characters as well, so using String.split() 'normally' will not do. For that, I would go with lookarounds already proposed, but with a simpler pattern:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Splitter {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    String str = "(30)";
    String[] results = str.split("(?<=[()])|(?=[()])");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(results)); // [(, 30, )]
  }
}
```

This pattern will use characters '(' and ')' as tokens to use for splitting, but keeps the tokens as well.

If you're interested, there's more discussion on using lookarounds in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206378/how-to-split-a-string-but-also-keep-the-delimiters).