# How to Split String, and Include splitter?

Tags: java, regex, string, arraylist, split

I have a txt file like this:

```
P 4 0 3 0 2 0 4 0 6 P 3 0 2 7 4 5 8 S 2 3 4 5 4 T 3 4 5 6 7 8 3
```

I read it into a string, and was trying to split the string. I need to split the String at P, S, T and store the string into an arraylist. I had this so far

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(content.split("P")));

        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
        {
            System.out.println(list.get(i));
        }
```

and got

```
ArrayList size: 3
4 0 3 0 2 0 4 0 6 
 3 0 2 7 4 5 8 S 2 3 4 5 4 T 3 4 5 6 7 8 3
```

while i want the strings in the ArrayList to be something like

```
P 4 0 3 0 2 0 4 0 6 
P 3 0 2 7 4 5 8 
S 2 3 4 5 4 
T 3 4 5 6 7 8 3
```

With each line representing a string.
How can i go about doing something like this?

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206378/how-to-split-a-string-but-also-keep-the-delimiters

Comment: @Sam Cheers! I didnt know what to search for, was searching for 'splitter' but I guess it was meant to be delimiter. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use regex [lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to split on the empty string `""` followed by a character `P|S|T` :

```
content.split("(?=[PST])");
```

Comment: Amazing! Thanks so much. Such a simple yet elegant solution :D