# How to split and store a string with dots and spaces into a string array including that spaces and dots

Tags: java

I know the split can be done with `split` functionality of java. I did that like in the below code

```
String[] sArr = name.split("[\\s.]+");
String newStr = "";
for (int i = 0; i < sArr.length; i++){
     newStr = newStr + " " + mymethod(sArr[i]);     
}
```

What i actually want to do is all the words in the string must pass through `mymethod` and reform the string. But on reforming i dont want to loss the dots and spaces which is actually there. For example `Mr. John` will remove the dot after reforming and would change in to `Mr John` which i don't want. So how to reform my string without losing anything in that actual string, but also each word to pass through `mymethod` also. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your expected output of `"Mr. John".split(...)`? For instance `["Mr. ", "John"]` or `["Mr", ". ", "John"]`.

Comment: ["Mr", ". ", "John"]

Comment: Check this post [How to split a string, but also keep the delimiters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206378/how-to-split-a-string-but-also-keep-the-delimiters)

Comment: That is working fine. But not working for dot brother.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over String using any loop char by char and find for `.` and space char, Then by using `substring()` method split Original string by storing index.

Code:-

```
List<String> arr=new ArrayList<String>();     // Array to hold splitted tokens
        String str="Mr. John abc. def";
        int strt=0; 
        int end=0;
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {  //Iterate over Original String
            if (str.charAt(i)=='.')               // Match . character
            {   
                end=i;
                arr.add(str.substring(strt,end));
                arr.add(str.charAt(i)+"");
                strt=i+1;
            }
            if (str.charAt(i)==' ')           // Match space character
            {   
                end=i;
                if (strt!=end)             // check if space is not just after . character
                arr.add(str.substring(strt,end));
                strt=i+1;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(arr);
```