# How to split a string by comma that is only followed by an alphanumeric character

Tags: java, regex, split

I am trying to separate a very large .cvs (255 columns) by using a BufferedReader that grabs each line and stores it in a string.

I'd like to be able to split it by a command and letter.
Ex:

`1,2,3,5,6` will split into
1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7

`hello,world,good day to you, Sir,test` will split into
hello | world | good day to you, Sir | test

notice how I only separated a comma that follows with an alphanumeric. The commas that precede a space are not separated, instead they are part of a sentence.

Comment: `,(?=[a-zA-Z0-9])` See [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/bSIpau/1) for demo.

Comment: You're looking for a "lookahead".

Answer (score 2):

For each string `a`:
`a.split(",(?=\\S)");`

Answer (score 1):

To split with a comma followed with an alpnanumeric char you may use

```
String pattern = ",(?=\\p{Alnum})";
```

Or, if you plan to support any Unicode letters, pass the `Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS`
(`(?U)`) option alongside the pattern:

```
String pattern = "(?U),(?=\\p{Alnum})";
```

See the [RegexPlanet regex demo](https://www.regexplanet.com/share/index.html?share=yyyyda6danr).

Java demo:

```
String s = "hello,world,good day to you, Sir,test,1,2";
String[] result = s.split(",(?=\\p{Alnum})");
for (String r:result) {
    System.out.println(r); 
}
```

Output:

```
hello
world
good day to you, Sir
test
1
2
```

Answer (score 0):

In this link there is an answer that explains the use of [Lookahead and Lookbehind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206378/how-to-split-a-string-but-also-keep-the-delimiters).
Here I leave a code that I believe can solve the problem you describe:

```
private static String[] mySplit(final String line, final char separator) {
    String regex = "((?<=(" + separator + "\\w)|(?=(" + separator + "\\w))))";
    String[] split = line.split(regex);

    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
        String token = split[i];
        if (token.startsWith(String.valueOf(separator))) {
            split[i + 1] = token.substring(1) + split[i + 1];
        } else {
            list.add(token);
        }
    }

    return list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
}

private static String concatenate(final String[] tokens, final char separator){
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
        builder.append(tokens[i]).append((i < tokens.length - 1) ? separator : "");
    }

    return builder.toString();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    final String line = "hello,world,good day to you, Sir,test";
    final String[] tokens = mySplit(line, ',');
    final String newLine = concatenate(tokens, '|');
    System.out.println("newLine = " + newLine);
}
```