# How to get list of pattern string and matcher string in java regex

Tags: java

First time I use Regex statement.

I have java regex statement, which split String by pattern with list of some characters.

```
String line = "F01T8B02S00003H04Z05C0.12500";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([BCFHSTZ])");
String[] commands = pattern.split(line);

for (String command : commands) {
 System.out.print(command);
}
```

output of above code is like (018020000304050.12500)

Actually I want output like this, ("F", "01", "T", "8", "B", "02", "S", "00003", "H", "04", "Z", "05", "C", "0.12500").

Means desired output is contains pattern character and split value both.

Can you please suggest me?

Comment: Is the same pattern always?

Comment: No. It may be some part missing. Like "F01B02S00003H04Z05C0.12500"

Comment: Have you checked the answer I posted? Did it work for you?

Comment: Yes, I got desired output, But i have to change regex statement. Thanks lot.

Comment: Then mark your question as correct...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [String#split](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) on `[A-Z]` which [keeps the delimiter as separated item](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2206432/1682559):

```
String line = "F01T8B02S00003H04Z05C0.12500";
String[] result = line.split("((?<=[A-Z])|(?=[A-Z]))");

System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(result));
```

Which will result in the String-array:

```
[F, 01, T, 8, B, 02, S, 00003, H, 04, Z, 05, C, 0.12500]
```

[**Try it online.**](https://tio.run/##TY9PC8IwDMXv@xRhp/Zgif9AmCIqiBdP86TsULchnbUbayoM9bPPjnowl4SX/N4jlXzKUVXc@z7X0lo4SmVeEUDjrlrlYEmSb89aFfDwK5ZSq8ztkoHkwxlAEEArU8IK4j2OT4stTlL0NT3g7IzzHYrxZI4YJ3@Et2hL6zR5aoCFbbQiFjO2Xq4um9E542@2/k085kkU4M5S@RC1I9F4G9KGVf4F4UhpsWlb2VlBdYhgIYDzIfcTffr@Cw)

Answer (score 3):

I've created a sample, try it and let me know if it's what you want.

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String line = "F01T8B02S00003H04Z05C0.12500";
    String pattern = "([A-Z][a-z]*)(((?=[A-Z][a-z]*|$))|\\d+(\\.\\d+)?)";

    Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

    Matcher m = r.matcher(line);
    HashMap<String, String> mHash = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    while (m.find()) {
        mHash.put(m.group(1), m.group(2));
    }

    System.out.println(mHash.toString());

}
```

}

Output is:

```
F 01
T 8
B 02
S 00003
H 04
Z 05
C 0.12500
```

Edit with `LinkedHashMap`

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String line = "F01T8B02S00003H04Z05C0.12500";
        String pattern = "([A-Z][a-z]*)(((?=[A-Z][a-z]*|$))|\\d+(\\.\\d+)?)";

        Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

        Matcher m = r.matcher(line);
        HashMap<String, String> mHash = new LinkedHashMap<>();

        while (m.find()) {
            mHash.put(m.group(1), m.group(2));
        }

        System.out.println(mHash.toString());

    }
}
```

Output is :

> {F=01, T=8, B=02, S=00003, H=04, Z=05, C=0.12500}

Answer (score 0):

Above all answer were correct.
I got solution by below code also.

```
String line = "F01T8B02S00003H04Z05C0.12500A03";

String[] commands = line.split("(?<=[BCFHSTZ])|(?=[BCFHSTZ])");

for (String str: commands) {
    System.out.print(str);
}
```

Thanks all for help.