# How to split a string into an array, inclusive of white spaces?

Tags: java

How can I split a string in java inclusive of white spaces?

```
String test = "1\t0.000000000\t192.168.0.24\t\t10.0.0.5\t\t98\t84\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t1";
```

The output array list should be like:

```
["1"," ","0.000000000", " ","192.168.0.24", " ", " ","10.0.0.5"...(well you get me)]
```

Comment: So you want to split the array, and also convert tabs to spaces?

Comment: Replace all whitespace with spaces first, then split by `(?<![\S])|(?![\S])`?

Comment: Similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206378/how-to-split-a-string-but-also-keep-the-delimiters

Comment: how do I replace all whitespace with spaces?

Comment: can someone please show me the actual code of how it works? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```java
      String text = "1\t0.000000000\t192.168.0.24\t\t10.0.0.5\t\t98\t84\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t1";

      String[] result = text.replaceAll("\t", "\t \t").split("(\t)+");
```