# string.split is not working when logical operator is present in the String

Tags: string, scala, split

I am having a string `">= 50.80"` I am trying split logical operator and float value using below

```
val result = ">= 50.80"
val Pattern = "(<[=>]?|==|>=?|\\&\\&|\\|\\|)".r
val Pattern(operator) = result
println(operator)
```

Error:

> Exception in thread "main" scala.MatchError: >= 50.80 (of class java.lang.String).

Comment: What doesn't work? It splits on `>=`, so it will be splitted into an array like `["", " 50.80"]`, making index `0` the empty string...?

Comment: Okie. I made a mistake. I want to split into [">=" , " 50.80"]. I want to support multiple logical operators such `<,>,==,<=,=>`.  Sometime space will not present between logical operator and float value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206378/how-to-split-a-string-but-also-keep-the-delimiters), negative lookbehind and lookahead can be leveraged to keep delimiters.

```
val result = ">= 50.80"
val str_split = result.split("(?<=(<[=>]?|==|>=|\\&\\&|\\|\\|))|(?=(<[=>]?|==|>=|\\&\\&|\\|\\|))")

for (v <- str_split) {
  println(v)
}
```