# How to split a string (based on a variety of delimiters) but without keeping whitespace?

Tags: java, regex, string, tokenize

I have Java strings which are boolean expressions with parentheses, `&`, `|`, and `!` as operators, and I want to split them into tokens.  For example:

`((!A1)&(B2|C3))` should become `"(","(","!","A1",")","&","(","B2","|","C3",")",")"`

Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2206432/3938965) I found that I can use Java's `String.split()` with a regex that includes lookahead and lookbehind clauses:

```java
List<String> tokens = "((!A1)&(B2|C3))".split("((?<=[!&()|])|(?=[!&()|]))")
```

My only problem is that whitespace will be included in the list of tokens.  For example if I were to write the expression as `( ( !A1 ) & ( B2 | C3 ) )` then my `split()` would produce at least four strings like `" "` and there'd be padding around my variables (e.g. `" A1 "`).

**How can I modify this `split` expression and regex to tokenize the string but not keep any of the witespace?**

Comment: Remove the spaces first, then split?

Comment: `"( ( !A1 ) & ( B2 | C3 ) )".replaceAll("\\s+", "")` What about this before `split`?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of split you can use this this regex to match what you want:

```
[!&()]|[^!&()\h]+
```

[RegEx Demo](http://%5B!&()%5D%7C%5B%5E!&()%5Ch%5D+)

**RegEx Details:**

- `[!&()]`: Match `!` or `&` or `(` or `)`
- `|`: OR
- `[^!&()\h]+`: Match any characters that is NOT `!`, `&`, `(`, `)` and a whitespace

**Code:**

```
final String regex = "[!&()]|[^!&()\\h]+";
final String string = "((!A1)&( B2 | C3 ))";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
while (matcher.find()) {
    result.add(matcher.group(0));
}

System.out.println(result);
```