# How to split string with round brackets in it?

Tags: java, arrays, string, split

Got a `String`:

```
String s = "1+2*(30+4/2-(1+2))*2+1";
```

Got `method` to split a string:

```
    public void convertString(String s) {
        String[] arr = s.split("(?<=[\\d.])(?=[^\\d.])|(?<=[^\\d.])(?=[\\d.])");
}
```

problem is:

```
    Output:
    [1, +, 2, *(, 30, +, 4, /, 2, -(, 1, +, 2, ))*, 2, +, 1] 
    //here round brackets store in the same cell with next symbol or prev symbol   *(,  ))*,
```

expected output:

```
[1, +, 2, *, (, 30, +, 4, /, 2, -, (, 1, +, 2, ), ), *, 2, +, 1]
// here round brackets store in a separate arr cells
```

I need to store round brackets in the separate array cells.

How to achieve it?

Comment: Do you really need to implement it using regexps?

Comment: if not using regexps, digit values may contains with errors, for example 30 may be store like 3, 0

Comment: I mean that using regular expressions might be a not very good idea for you (especially for recursive parenthesis), and what you might need is implementing a lexer whose classic problem is parsing math expressions like the one you've provided.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47570657/1707353) looks like a reasonable implementation. You might be able to substitute `+*/-` with `+*/-()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex literally splits at any location that goes from non-digit to digit, or vice versa.  It explicitly does not split between non-digits.

So give your current method, the fix would be

```
public void convertString(String s) {
    String[] arr = s.split("(?<=[\\d.])(?=[^\\d.])|(?<=[^\\d.])(?=[^\\d.])|(?<=[^\\d.])(?=[\\d.])");
}
```

That said, it's probably better ways of doing this.  A simple regex match, where the expression is either a single-non-digit, or an eager group of digits, will already be easier than this.

Answer (score 0):

don't include brackets in your regex, only take out the specific punctuation which you don't want. you can create an array and use a loop to put the numbers into the array.
https://regex101.com/r/tHjoYn/1/ - here you can test for the regex you want.