# Split string using java regex

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to split this string :

> Testing package [Store Management]([https://www.Testing.com/content/zone_store_mgmt_policy\"Store](https://www.Testing.com/content/zone_store_mgmt_policy%5C%22Store) Management Policy") Test package2

using regex, so it splits into 3 parts:

1. Testing package
2. [Store Management]   ([https://www.Testing.com/content/zone_store_spl_policy\"Store](https://www.Testing.com/content/zone_store_spl_policy%5C%22Store) Management Policy")
3. Test package2

The rule is split the string when the pattern `[any characters](any characters)` is found.

This is what I tried :

```
String values ="Testing package [Store Management](https://www.Testing.com/content/zone_store_spl_policy\"Store Management Policy\") Test package2";
pattern = Pattern.compile("(?:\\[.*\\]\\(.*\\))");
valueArray = pattern.split(values);
for (String s: valueArray) 
           System.out.println(s);
```

But the output is:

Testing package
Test package2

I need an array containing 3 strings as above.

Comment: Please familiarize yourself with the editor in StackOverflow. Take some time and format your question properly. It is unreadable in the current state.

Comment: It's not clear what exactly your string is because you haven't set it apart in any way. As far as I can tell `Test package2 using regex. so it looks like this array` is part of the string, but I'm sure "so it looks like this array" isn't really part of it.

Comment: The problem is that you have a `?` at the end making `""` valid for the regex. This is why it detects every character alone.

Comment: When I removed the ? at the end I got the output as Testing package 
 Test package2 but the value [Store Management]
(https://www.Testing.com/content/zone_store_spl_policy\"Store Management Policy\")
is missing in the array.

Comment: Use [this code](https://ideone.com/ghjBu8) (see [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cDvOvq/1)).

Comment: Tried it but got 4 elements as below[Testing package, [Store Management], (https://w...content-available-to-author-only...g.com/content/zone_store_mgmt_policy"Store Management Policy"), Test package2]    I need 3 elements whatever comes in []() as one element [Store Management] (https://w...content-available-to-author-only...g.com/content/zone_store_mgmt_policy"Store Management Policy")

Comment: Great, then it is even simpler: [here is your solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44084475/3832970).

Answer (score 1):

It will be far simpler to use group matching then simple split as you have different delimiters for each portion

Try the following (using very naïve pattern matching)

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class RegexMatches {
   public static void main( String args[] ) {
      String line = "Testing package [Store Management](https://www.Testing.com/content/zone_store_mgmt_policy\"Store Management Policy\") Test package2";
      String pattern = "(.*)\\s*(\\[.*\\])(\\(.*\\))\\s*(.*)";

      // Create a Pattern object
      Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

      // Now create matcher object.
      Matcher m = r.matcher(line);
      
      if (m.find( )) {
         System.out.println(m.group(1));
         System.out.println(m.group(2));
         System.out.println(m.group(3));
         System.out.println(m.group(4));
      } else {
         System.out.println("NO MATCH");
      }
   }
}
```

Some reference:

[On capturing groups in regex](https://regexone.com/lesson/capturing_groups)

[Java Matcher](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group(int))