# Decipher the sequence using Java 8

Tags: java, arrays, string, ascii

Steps for Deciphering the message

1. remove 3 at end of the string
2. replace ASCII values at even places(number clusters) with corresponding characters value.
3. replace * with spacing " ".
4. reverse  the string
5. swap case of string- lowercase to upper case and vice versa.

Sample input: `?85O89*69R65*87O104*33I1043`
Require output: `Hi! How are you?`
This is the whole method that I have written.

```
public String deciphering(String ciphered) {
        StringBuilder a = new StringBuilder(ciphered);
        StringBuilder b = a.deleteCharAt(a.length()-1);
        char[] ch = new char[b.length()];
        StringBuilder c = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < b.length(); i++) {
            ch[i] = b.charAt(i);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < ch.length; i++) {
            if(!Character.isDigit(ch[i]))
            {
                c.append(ch[i]);
            }else
            {
                String temp = new String();
                while(Character.isDigit(ch[i]) &&(i<b.length())){
                   temp = temp + ch[i];
                   i++;
               }
                int number = Integer.parseInt(temp);
                char p = (char)number;
               c.append(p);
            }
        }

        String d = c.toString();
        String e = d.replace('*', ' ');
        StringBuffer f = new StringBuffer(e);
        StringBuffer g = f.reverse();
        for (int i = 0; i < g.length(); i++) {

                if (Character.isLowerCase(g.charAt(i))){
                    char x = Character.toUpperCase(g.charAt(i));
                    g.setCharAt(i, x);
                } else if (Character.isUpperCase(g.charAt(i))) {
                    char x = Character.toLowerCase(g.charAt(i));
                    g.setCharAt(i, x);
                }
        }

        return g.toString();
    }
```

Comment: Your requirement is unclear; it's definitely not "even positions", since your first '3' is in an even position and the second '3' in an odd one.

Comment: Actually, it is like an encrypted string where each number cluster represents an ASCII character

Comment: FYI, the `char` type in Java is legacy, essentially broken. As a 16-bit value, `char` is incapable of representing most characters. Learn to use [code point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) integer numbers instead.

Comment: @Biswaroop: so what would `'1', '1', '1', '1'` be? 111 followed by 1? Or 11 followed by 11? Or 4 times a 1? It's still unclear how this is supposed to work and therefore it's unclear what your logic should be.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You are incrementing i twice past the last digit of a chunk - when you exit your inner loop i is indexing the first non-digit character, then when you reach the end of the for loop body, the for loop is incrementing i again.

Answer (score 0):

It may be better to split the input string into parts with non-digit delimiters and keep the delimiters using the following regular expression (using look-ahead and look-behind [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206378/how-to-split-a-string-but-also-keep-the-delimiters)) after removing the last character:

`str.substring(0, str.length() - 1).split("(?<=\\D)|(?=\\D)")`

Then Stream API may be used to convert each string into a separate character and *insert* these characters into prepared `StringBuilder` to implement reverse order in the result:

```java
public static String decipher(String str) {
    
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str.length());
    
    Arrays.stream(
            str.substring(0, str.length() - 1).split("(?<=\\D)|(?=\\D)")
        )
        .map(p -> p.matches("\\d+") ? (char) Integer.parseInt(p): p.charAt(0))
        .map(c -> c == '*' ? ' ' 
            : Character.isLowerCase(c) ? Character.toUpperCase(c) 
            : Character.isUpperCase(c) ? Character.toLowerCase(c)
            : c
        )
        .forEach(c -> sb.insert(0, c));
        
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Test:

```java
System.out.println(decipher("?85O89*69R65*87O104*33I1043"));
```

Output:

```
Hi! How are you?
```