# Get list of the substring from the string based on the String delimiter

Tags: java, string

```
String s = "I like an orange as well as apple but mostly apple. apple, orange are the best fruits.";

String[] delimiter = {"orange", "apple"};
```

I wanted to split this string like below:

> {"I like an ", "orange", " as well as ", "apple", " but mostly ", "apple", ".", "apple", ",", "orange", " are the best fruits."}

In above, I have split the string based on the fruit orange and apple, but both the fruits are also the part of list of substring.

Comment: `but mostly apple.` and `" but mostly ", ". "` dont match the requirements

Comment: @XtremeBaumer I made a blunder, now I have updated the question.

Comment: No it is not. It is not giving an appropriate answer for me.

Comment: Its not giving you a ready to copy answer, yes. You still need to do some work but its giving you everything you need to know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2206432/12087117):

```
public class Solution {
    public static String[] getTokens(String str, String[] delimeters) {
        if (delimeters.length == 0) {
            return new String[]{str};
        }
        // Create regex: ((?<=delimeter)|(?=delimeter))
        String delimetersConcatenatedWithOr = "(" + String.join(")|(", delimeters) + ")";
        String regex = "((?<=" + delimetersConcatenatedWithOr + ")|(?=" + delimetersConcatenatedWithOr + "))";
        // Split using regex
        return str.split(regex);
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String str = "I like an orange as well as apple but mostly apple. apple, orange are the best fruits.";
        String[] delimeters = {"apple", "orange"};
        for (String token : getTokens(str, delimeters)) {
            System.out.println("{" + token + "}");
        }
    }
}
```