# Can you use zero-width matching regex in String split?

Tags: java, regex, split, delimiter

```
System.out.println(
    Arrays.deepToString(
        "abc<def>ghi".split("(?:<)|(?:>)")
    )
);
```

This prints `[abc, def, ghi]`, as if I had split on `"<|>"`. I want it to print `[abc, <def>, ghi]`. Is there a way to work some regex magic to accomplish what I want here?

---

Perhaps a simpler example:

```
System.out.println(
    Arrays.deepToString(
        "Hello! Oh my!! Good bye!!".split("(?:!+)")
    )
);
```

This prints `[Hello,  Oh my,  Good bye]`. I want it to print `[Hello!,  Oh my!!,  Good bye!!]`.
`.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/275768/is-there-a-way-to-split-strings-with-string-split-and-include-the-delimiters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to information from Cine, I *think* these are the answers I'm looking for:

```
System.out.println(
    Arrays.deepToString(
        "abc<def>ghi<x><x>".split("(?=<)|(?<=>)")
    )
); // [abc, <def>, ghi, <x>, <x>]


System.out.println(
    Arrays.deepToString(
        "Hello! Oh my!! Good bye!! IT WORKS!!!".split("(?<=!++)")
    )
); // [Hello!,  Oh my!!,  Good bye!!,  IT WORKS!!!]
```

Now, the second one was honestly discovered by experimenting with all the different quantifiers. Neither greedy nor reluctant work, but possessive does.

I'm still not sure why.

Comment: Your second example isn't supposed to work. :-/  It should throw a PatternSyntaxException because the lookbehind has no obvious maximum length.  That your regex compiles is a bug; that it *works* is mind boggling--and not to be relied on.  Here's what you should be using: `(?<=!)(?!!)`.  That will work in any regex flavor that supports lookaheads and lookbehinds.

Comment: The bug has been reported, if that's what you mean.  I would advise you not to get into the habit of using variable-width expressions in lookbehinds in any case; very few regex flavors support that capability, and there's usually a better way anyway.

Answer (score 3):

You need to take a look at zero width matching constructs:

```
(?=X)   X, via zero-width positive lookahead
(?!X)   X, via zero-width negative lookahead
(?<=X)  X, via zero-width positive lookbehind
(?<!X)  X, via zero-width negative lookbehind
```

Comment: Yes, I misunderstood what `(?:`...`)` is for.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\b` (word boundary) as what to look for as it is zero-width and use that as the anchor for looking for `<` and `>`.

```
String s = "abc<def>ghi";
String[] bits = s.split("(?<=>)\\b|\\b(?=<)");
for (String bit : bits) {
  System.out.println(bit);
}
```

Output:

```
abc
<def>
ghi
```

Now that isn't a general solution. You will probably need to write a custom split method for that.

Your second example suggests it's not really `split()` you're after but a regex matching loop. For example:

```
String s = "Hello! Oh my!! Good bye!!";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(.*?!+)\\s*");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
while (m.find()) {
  System.out.println("[" + m.group(1) + "]");
}
```

Output:

```
[Hello!]
[Oh my!!]
[Good bye!!]
```

Comment: Would you kindly comment on my answer see if there's anything wrong with it? Thanks.