# Java split is eating my characters

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I have a string like this `String str = "la$le\\$li$lo"`.

I want to split it to get the following output `"la","le\\$li","lo"`. The \$ is a $ escaped so it should be left in the output.

But when I do  `str.split("[^\\\\]\\$")` y get `"l","le\\$l","lo"`.

From what I get my regex is matching a$ and i$ and removing then. Any idea of how to get my characters back?

Thanks

Comment: `String str = "la$le\$li$lo"`?  do you mean  `String str = "la$le\\$li$lo"` ??

Comment: Can the escapes be escaped as well? If so, regex will not do (regex-es can't count!).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use zero-width matching assertions:

```
    String str = "la$le\\$li$lo";
    System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(
        str.split("(?<!\\\\)\\$")
    )); // prints "[la, le\$li, lo]"
```

The regex is essentially

```
(?<!\\)\$
```

It uses negative lookbehind to assert that there is not a preceding `\`.

#### See also

- [regular-expressions.info/Lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

---

#### More examples of splitting on assertions

Simple sentence splitting, keeping punctuation marks:

```
    String str = "Really?Wow!This.Is.Awesome!";
    System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(
        str.split("(?<=[.!?])")
    )); // prints "[Really?, Wow!, This., Is., Awesome!]"
```

Splitting a long string into fixed-length parts, using `\G`

```
    String str = "012345678901234567890";
    System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(
        str.split("(?<=\\G.{4})")
    )); // prints "[0123, 4567, 8901, 2345, 6789, 0]"
```

Using a lookbehind/lookahead combo:

```
    String str = "HelloThereHowAreYou";
    System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(
        str.split("(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])")
    )); // prints "[Hello, There, How, Are, You]"
```

#### Related questions

- [Can you use zero-width matching regex in String split?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2406633/can-you-use-zero-width-matching-regex-in-string-split)
- [Backreferences in lookbehind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2734977/backreferences-in-lookbehind)
- [How do I convert CamelCase into human-readable names in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559759/how-do-i-convert-camelcase-into-human-readable-names-in-java)

Comment: @Fenris: the difference is that if `$` is the first character, my regex can still split on it, and yours can't, because it insists that there is a character preceding it (that is not a slash).

Answer (score 2):

The reason a$ and i$ are getting removed is that the regexp `[^\\]\$` matches any character that is not '\' followed by '$'. You need to use [zero width assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

This is the same problem people have trying to find q not followed by u.

A first cut at the proper regexp is `/(?<!\\)\$/` ( `"(?<!\\\\)\\$"` in java )

```
class Test {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  String regexp = "(?<!\\\\)\\$";
  System.out.println( java.util.Arrays.toString( "1a$1e\\$li$lo".split(regexp) ) );
 }
}
```

Yields:
`[1a, 1e\$li, lo]`

Answer (score 1):

You can try first replacing "\$" with another string, such as the URL Encoding for $ ("%24"), and then splitting:

```
String splits[] = str.replace("\$","%24").split("[^\\\\]\\$");
for(String str : splits){
   str = str.replace("%24","\$");
}
```

More generally, if str is constructed by something like

```
str = a + "$" + b + "$" + c
```

Then you can URLEncode a, b and c before appending them together

```
import java.net.URLEncoder.encode;
...
str = encode(a) + "$" + encode(b) + "$" + encode(c)
```

Comment: Good point. I updated my response for a more general solution that assumes that you are splitting str because it really consists of three strings you were appending together in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.regex.*;
public class Test {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        String str = "la$le\\$li$lo";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(.+?)([^\\\\]\\$)");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
        while (m.find()) {
            System.out.println(m.group(1));
            System.out.println(m.group(2));
        }
    }
}
```

gives

```
l
a$
le\$l
i$
```