# Regex split string but keep separators

Tags: c#, regex, split

I'd like to do a [Regex.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ze12yx1d.aspx) on some separators but I'd like to keep the separators. To give an example of what I'm trying:

```
"abc[s1]def[s2][s3]ghi" --> "abc", "[s1]", "def", "[s2]", "[s3]", "ghi"
```

The regular expression I've come up with is `new Regex("\\[|\\]|\\]\\[")`. However, this gives me the following:

```
"abc[s1]def[s2][s3]ghi" --> "abc", "s1", "def", "s2", "", "s3", "ghi"
```

The separators have disappeared (which makes sense given my regex). Is there a way to write the regex so that the separators themselves are preserved?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use zero-length maching lookarounds; you want to split on

```
(?=\[)|(?<=\])
```

That is, anywhere where we assert a match of a literal `[` ahead, or where we assert a match of literal `]` behind.

As a C# string literal, this is

```
@"(?=\[)|(?<=\])"
```

#### See also

- [regular-expressions.info/Lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

#### Related questions

- [Java split is eating my characters.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2819933/java-split-is-eating-my-characters/) -- has many examples

---

#### Example in Java

```
    System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(
        "abc[s1]def[s2][s3]ghi".split("(?=\\[)|(?<=\\])")
    ));
    // prints "[abc, [s1], def, [s2], [s3], ghi]"

    System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(
        "abc;def;ghi;".split("(?<=;)")
    ));
    // prints "[abc;, def;, ghi;]"

    System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(
        "OhMyGod".split("(?=(?!^)[A-Z])")
    ));
    // prints "[Oh, My, God]"
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `.Matches` instead of `.Split`, example (http://www.ideone.com/gUjRM):

```
string x = "abc[s1]def[s2][s3]ghi";
var r = new Regex(@"[^\[]+|\[[^\]]+\]");
var ms = r.Matches(x);
// do stuff with the MatchCollection `ms`.
```