# How do I split a string and then rejoin it?

Tags: c#, string, join, split

I have the following string in C#.

```
"aaa,bbbb.ccc|dddd:eee"
```

I then split it with `new char[] {',','.','|',':'}`.  How would I rejoin this string in the same order as before with the same characters?  So the list would end up the exact same as it was before.

EXAMPLE

```
string s = "aaa,bbbb.ccc|dddd:eee";
string[] s2 = s.Split(new char[] {',','.','|',':'});
// now s2 = {"aaa", "bbbb", "ccc", "dddd", "eee"}
// lets assume I done some operation, and
// now s2 = {"xxx", "yyy", "zzz", "1111", "222"}

s = s2.MagicJoin(~~~~~~);  // I need this

// now s = "xxx,yyy.zzz|1111:222";
```

EDIT

the `char[]` in above sample just sample, not in same order or even will not all appear in same time in real world.

EDIT

Just a thought, how about use Regex.split, then first split by `char[]` get a `string[]`, then use `not the char[]` to split get another `string[]`, later just put them back. Maybe work but I do not know how to code it.

Comment: I think you may have to do it manually.

Comment: are the delineators always in the exact same order?

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2910536/regex-split-string-but-keep-separators to see if it helps.

Comment: will the string always be `$1,$2.$3|$4:$5`?  Or could there be an unknown number of commas, periods, pipes etc?

Comment: I think some way. Easy way is find and save chars, what are deleted, when you done split.

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler just to keep the original string around?

Comment: Eric, it's not clear to me what your requirements are. Some examples of inputs and outputs would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be easier to do this with the Regex class:

```
input = Regex.Replace(input, @"[^,.|:]+", DoSomething);
```

Where DoSomething is a method or lambda that transforms the item in question, e.g.:

```
string DoSomething(Match m)
{
    return m.Value.ToUpper();
}
```

For this example the output string for "aaa,bbbb.ccc|dddd:eee" would be "AAA,BBBB.CCC|DDDD:EEE".

If you use a lambda you can very easily keep state around, like this:

```
int i = 0;
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace("aaa,bbbb.ccc|dddd:eee", @"[^,.|:]+",
    _ => (++i).ToString()));
```

Outputs:

```
1,2.3|4:5
```

It just depends on what kind of transformation you're doing to the items.

Comment: thank, I think this way works, although not I initially thought, but I start in a wrong way

Answer (score 3):

Here you go - this works any combination of delimiters in any order, allowing also for the situation where a delimiter is not actually found in the string either.  It's taken me a while to come up with this and, having posted it, it looks more complex than any other answer!

Ah well, I'll keep it here anyway.

```
public static string SplitAndReJoin(string str, char[] delimiters, 
  Func<string[], string[]> mutator)
{
  //first thing to know is which of the delimiters are 
  //actually in the string, and in what order
  //Using ToArray() here to get the total count of found delimiters
  var delimitersInOrder = (from ci in
                            (from c in delimiters
                             from i in FindIndexesOfAll(str, c)
                             select new { c, i })
                          orderby ci.i
                          select ci.c).ToArray();
  if (delimitersInOrder.Length == 0)
    return str;

  //now split and mutate the string
  string[] strings = str.Split(delimiters);
  strings = mutator(strings);
  //now build a format string
  //note - this operation is much more complicated if you wish to use 
  //StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries
  string formatStr = string.Join("",
    delimitersInOrder.Select((c, i) => string.Format("{{{0}}}", i)
      + c));
  //deals with the 'perfect' split - i.e. there's always two values
  //either side of a delimiter
  if (strings.Length > delimitersInOrder.Length)
    formatStr += string.Format("{{{0}}}", strings.Length - 1);

  return string.Format(formatStr, strings);
}

public static IEnumerable<int> FindIndexesOfAll(string str, char c)
{
  int startIndex = 0;
  int lastIndex = -1;

  while(true)
  {
    lastIndex = str.IndexOf(c, startIndex);
    if (lastIndex != -1)
    {
      yield return lastIndex;
      startIndex = lastIndex + 1;
    }
    else
      yield break;
  }
}
```

And here's a test you can use to validate it:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestSplitAndReJoin()
{
  //note - mutator does nothing
  Assert.AreEqual("a,b", SplitAndReJoin("a,b", ",".ToCharArray(), s => s));
  //insert a 'z' in front of every sub string.
  Assert.AreEqual("zaaa,zbbbb.zccc|zdddd:zeee", SplitAndReJoin("aaa,bbbb.ccc|dddd:eee",
    ",.|:".ToCharArray(), s => s.Select(ss => "z" + ss).ToArray()));
  //re-ordering of delimiters + mutate
  Assert.AreEqual("zaaa,zbbbb.zccc|zdddd:zeee", SplitAndReJoin("aaa,bbbb.ccc|dddd:eee",
    ":|.,".ToCharArray(), s => s.Select(ss => "z" + ss).ToArray()));
  //now how about leading or trailing results?
  Assert.AreEqual("a,", SplitAndReJoin("a,", ",".ToCharArray(), s => s));
  Assert.AreEqual(",b", SplitAndReJoin(",b", ",".ToCharArray(), s => s));
}
```

Note that I've assumed you need to be able to do something with the elements of the array, to manipulate the individual strings before joining them back together again - otherwise presumably you would just keep the original string!

The method builds a dynamic format string.  No warranty here on efficiency :)

Comment: if I do not now the order of the `char[]` used for split, and I just assume it might have these `char[]`. I wanna make a common function for any string, please advice.

Answer (score 3):

Here's `MagicSplit`:

```
public IEnumerable<Tuple<string,char>> MagicSplit(string input, char[] split)
{    
    var buffer = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var c in input)
    {
        if (split.Contains(c)) 
        {
            var result = buffer.ToString();
            buffer.Clear();
            yield return Tuple.Create(result,c);
        }
        else
        {
            buffer.Append(c);
        }
    }
    yield return Tuple.Create(buffer.ToString(),' ');
}
```

And two types of `MagicJoin`:

```
public string MagicJoin(IEnumerable<Tuple<string,char>> split)
{
    return split.Aggregate(new StringBuilder(), (sb, tup) => sb.Append(tup.Item1).Append(tup.Item2)).ToString();
}

public string MagicJoin(IEnumerable<string> strings, IEnumerable<char> chars)
{
    return strings.Zip(chars, (s,c) => s + c.ToString()).Aggregate(new StringBuilder(), (sb, s) => sb.Append(s)).ToString();
}
```

Usages:

```
var s = "aaa,bbbb.ccc|dddd:eee";

// simple
var split = MagicSplit(s, new char[] {',','.','|',':'}).ToArray();
var joined = MagicJoin(split);    

// if you want to change the strings
var strings = split.Select(tup => tup.Item1).ToArray();
var chars = split.Select(tup => tup.Item2).ToArray();
strings[0] = "test";
var joined = MagicJoin(strings,chars);
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
var x = "aaa,bbbb.ccc|dddd:eee";

var matches = Regex.Matches(x, "(?<Value>[^\\.,|\\:]+)(?<Separator>[\\.,|\\:]?)");

var result = new StringBuilder();

foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    result.AppendFormat("{0}{1}", match.Groups["Value"], match.Groups["Separator"]);
}

Console.WriteLine(result.ToString());
Console.ReadLine();
```

Or if you love LINQ (which I do):

```
var x = "aaa,bbbb.ccc|dddd:eee";
var matches = Regex.Matches(x, "(?<Value>[^\\.,|\\:]+)(?<Separator>[\\.,|\\:]?)");
var reassembly = matches.Cast<Match>().Aggregate(new StringBuilder(), (a, v) => a.AppendFormat("{0}{1}", v.Groups["Value"], v.Groups["Separator"])).ToString();
Console.WriteLine(reassembly);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Needless to say that you could do something with the parts before re-assembling which I would presume is the point of this exercise