# C# Regex - Split and Keep Splitter

Tags: c#, regex, regex-lookarounds

Related:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2910549/194031

I have a string like:

```
"abc defgh <!inc(C:\my files\abc.txt)!>kdi kdkd<!inc(C:\my files\abc.txt)!>"
```

and I want to get:

```
["abc defgh ", "C:\my files\abc.txt", "kdi kdkd", "C:\my files\abc.txt"]
```

Also, I don't want

```
"abc <!inc(C:\my files\abc.txt adf" (missing end bracket)
```

to get split.

Based on the related question and other similar answers, I need to use look aheads, but I can't figure out how to use them while accomplishing removing the tags and not splitting if part of the tags are missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might help you get started.  You'll probably need to tailor it some more.

```
Regex.Split("...", @"<!inc\((?=.*?\)!>)|(?<=<!inc\(.*?)\)!>");
```

Expression break down

```
<!inc\(
(?=.*?\)!>)    // this is the positive lookahead to make sure that the string ')!>`
               // exists before counting this as a match
|
(?<=<!inc\(.*?) // positive look behind to make sure '<!inc(' shows up before
\)!>
```

Comment: +1 - There is no need to wrap `.*?` in parens in the look-behind though.

Comment: `.*?` isn't wrapped, but it does look like it

Answer (score 2):

This is your regex

```
<!inc\((?=[^)]+\)!>)|(?<=<!inc\([^)]+)\)!>
```

it splits on (and removes) every `<!inc(` if and only if it has a matching `)!>` (and vice versa).

Comment: Thanks Tomalak!  This almost works for all cases, except that when I go to multiline input, it no longer splits properly.  Singleline, it was fine though.  Sorry, I didn't mention multiline earlier, I didn't realize it might affect the answers.  I also tried using the RegexOptions.Multiline, but that didn't help.

Comment: @Chad Multiline or singleline *should* not affect this regex, at least I can't see how.