# Read file and write in another file in reverse order with "a" and "the" stripped off

Tags: c#, streamreader, filereader, memory-mapped-files

I want to write a program using C# reads a file and spits out another file that has all the words in original file in reverse order and is stripped of all words like "a" and "the".

```
using (FileStream stream = File.OpenRead("C:\\file1.txt"))
using (FileStream writeStream = File.OpenWrite("D:\\file2.txt"))
{
    BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(stream);
    BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(writeStream);

    // create a buffer to hold the bytes 
    byte[] buffer = new Byte[1024];
    int bytesRead;

    // while the read method returns bytes
    // keep writing them to the output stream
    while ((bytesRead =
            stream.Read(buffer, 0, 1024)) > 0)
    {
        writeStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }
}
```

I've implemented the previous code. How reverse and spit out characters "a" and "the".

Comment: I would use the StreamReader and StreamWriter classes.

Answer (score 5):

`File` have static helpers that deal with reading and writing text - should be enough for most real cases where text is somewhat small:

```
File.WriteAllText(destinationFilePath,
String.Join(" ",
  File.ReadAllText(sourceFilePath)
   .Split(' ')
   .Where(s=> s != "a" && s != "the").Reverse())
);
```

If your source contains sentences and not just words separate by spaces - use regex to tokenize the text - [Regex split string but keep separators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2910536/regex-split-string-but-keep-separators) instead of `String.Split`.