# Split string along regex, but keep matches

Tags: string, go, split

I want to split a string on a regular expresion, but preserve the matches.

I have tried splitting the string on a regex, but it throws away the matches. I have also tried using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2910536/regex-split-string-but-keep-separators), but I am not very good at translating code from language to language, let alone C#.

```golang
re := regexp.MustCompile(`\d`)
array := re.Split("ab1cd2ef3", -1)
```

I need the value of array to be ["ab", "1", "cd", "2", "ef", "3"], but the value of array is ["ab", "cd", "ef"]. No errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The kind of regex support in the link you have pointed out is NOT available in Go regex package. You can read the [related discussion](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/18868).

What you want to achieve (as per the sample given) can be done using regex to match digits or non-digits.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    str := "ab1cd2ef3"
    r := regexp.MustCompile(`(\d|[^\d]+)`)
    fmt.Println(r.FindAllStringSubmatch(str, -1))
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/L-ElvkDky53

Output:

```
[[ab ab] [1 1] [cd cd] [2 2] [ef ef] [3 3]]
```

Comment: Can I do the same for multiple separators? It seems like I cant. `( \(\)|[^ \(\)]+)`

Comment: It is just regex to match tokens. So as long as you can represent token separately using regex, you can have multiple of those separated by `|`. If you can provide some sample string, it will be easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible with the current regexp package, but the `Split` could be easily extended to such behavior.

This should work for your case:

```
func Split(re *regexp.Regexp, s string, n int) []string {
    if n == 0 {
        return nil
    }

    matches := re.FindAllStringIndex(s, n)
    strings := make([]string, 0, len(matches))

    beg := 0
    end := 0
    for _, match := range matches {
        if n > 0 && len(strings) >= n-1 {
            break
        }

        end = match[0]
        if match[1] != 0 {
            strings = append(strings, s[beg:end])
        }
        beg = match[1]
        // This also appends the current match
        strings = append(strings, s[match[0]:match[1]])
    }

    if end != len(s) {
        strings = append(strings, s[beg:])
    }

    return strings
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Dumb solutions. Add separator in the string and split with separator.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    re := regexp.MustCompile(`\d+`)
    input := "ab1cd2ef3"
    sep := "|"

    indexes := re.FindAllStringIndex(input, -1)
    fmt.Println(indexes)

    move := 0
    for _, v := range indexes {
        p1 := v[0] + move
        p2 := v[1] + move
        input = input[:p1] + sep + input[p1:p2] + sep + input[p2:]
        move += 2
    }

    result := strings.Split(input, sep)

    fmt.Println(result)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `bufio.Scanner`:

```
package main

import (
   "bufio"
   "strings"
)

func digit(data []byte, eof bool) (int, []byte, error) {
   for i, b := range data {
      if '0' <= b && b <= '9' {
         if i > 0 {
            return i, data[:i], nil
         }
         return 1, data[:1], nil
      }
   }
   return 0, nil, nil
}

func main() {
   s := bufio.NewScanner(strings.NewReader("ab1cd2ef3"))
   s.Split(digit)
   for s.Scan() {
      println(s.Text())
   }
}
```

https://golang.org/pkg/bufio#Scanner.Split