# Regex to split a string (in Java) so that spaces are preserved?

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I need to split a string (in Java) into individual words ... but I need to preserve spaces.

An example of the text I need to split is something like this:
ABC    . . . . DEF . . . . GHI

I need to see "ABC", "   . . . .", "DEF", ". . . .", and "GHI".

Obviously splitting on the space character `\s` isn't going to work, as all the spaces get swallowed up as one space.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want ". . . . " and not ". ", ". ", ". ", ". "? You only want to split on space sometimes? What are the rules exactly?

Comment: Actually, that would have been fine also ... I just needed the spaces preserved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks guys, that gave me the lead I needed ... I'm using `(?<=[\\s])` and it works exactly the way I want!

Answer (score 5):

Looks like you can just split on `\b` in this case (`"\\b"` as a string literal).

Generally you want to split on zero-width matching constructs, which `\b` is, but also lookarounds can be used.

#### Related questions

- [Java split is eating my characters.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2819933/java-split-is-eating-my-characters)

---

#### Splitting based on a custom word boundary

If `\b` isn't fitting your definition, you can always define your own boundaries using assertions.

For example, the following regex splits on the boundary between a meta character class `X` and its complement

```
(?=[X])(?<=[^X])|(?=[^X])(?<=[X])
```

In the following example, we define `X` to be `\d`:

```
    System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(
        "007james123bond".split(
            "(?=[X])(?<=[^X])|(?=[^X])(?<=[X])".replace("X", "\\d")
        )
    )); // prints "[007, james, 123, bond]"
```

Here's another example where `X` is `a-z$`:

```
    System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(
        "$dollar . . blah-blah   $more gimme".split(
            "(?=[X])(?<=[^X])|(?=[^X])(?<=[X])".replace("X", "a-z$")
        )
    )); // prints "[$dollar,  . . , blah, -, blah,    , $more,  , gimme]"
```

Comment: Tried that ... but some of the characters in my string are 'non-word' characters (like `&`), so they get eaten up.  I need a a character sequence such as `&N` to be considered a word.

Comment: @david: assertions/lookarounds is most definitely the answer here; you need to address Mark Byers' comment. What are the rules exactly?

Comment: @david: If you have the time, write up your own answer. I'd like to see what you're trying to do and how you've accomplished it. You may even get {Self Learner}.