# Need to split a string into two parts in java

Tags: java, regex, string, regex-lookarounds

I have a string which contains a contiguous chunk of digits and then a contiguous chunk of characters. I need to split them into two parts (one integer part, and one string).

I tried using `String.split("\\D", 1)`, but it is eating up first character.
I checked all the String API and didn't find a suitable method.

Is there any method for doing this thing?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use lookarounds: `str.split("(?<=\\d)(?=\\D)")`

```
String[] parts = "123XYZ".split("(?<=\\d)(?=\\D)");
System.out.println(parts[0] + "-" + parts[1]);
// prints "123-XYZ"
```

`\d` is the character class for digits; `\D` is its negation. So this zero-matching assertion matches the position where the preceding character is a digit `(?<=\d)`, and the following character is a non-digit `(?=\D)`.

#### References

- [regular-expressions.info/Lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) and [Character Class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)

#### Related questions

- [Java split is eating my characters.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2819933/java-split-is-eating-my-characters/)
- [Is there a way to split strings with String.split() and include the delimiters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275768/is-there-a-way-to-split-strings-with-string-split-and-include-the-delimiters/)

---

#### Alternate solution using limited split

The following also works:

```
    String[] parts = "123XYZ".split("(?=\\D)", 2);
    System.out.println(parts[0] + "-" + parts[1]);
```

This splits just before we see a non-digit. This is much closer to your original solution, except that since it doesn't actually match the non-digit character, it doesn't "eat it up". Also, it uses `limit` of `2`, which is really what you want here.

#### API links

- [`String.split(String regex, int limit)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)

  - If the limit `n` is greater than zero then the pattern will be applied at most `n - 1` times, the array's length will be no greater than `n`, and the array's last entry will contain all input beyond the last matched delimiter.

Answer (score 3):

There's always an old-fashioned way:

```
private String[] split(String in) {    
  int indexOfFirstChar = 0;
  for (char c : in.toCharArray()) {
    if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
      indexOfFirstChar++;
    } else {
      break;
    } 
  }    
  return new String[]{in.substring(0,indexOfFirstChar), in.substring(indexOfFirstChar)};
}
```

(hope it works with digit-only or char-only Strings too - can't test it here - if not, take it as a general idea)