# How to split a String into 2 parts in Java?

Tags: java, string

I'm learning Java and I need to split a String into 2 parts. For example I get the address field from database and it looks like this: "Piazza Victoria 3425" and I need to split this into 2 fields, the first is streetName and contains "Piazza Victoria" and the second is streetNo and contains "3485". How can I do that? Thanks in advance!

Comment: what have you tried? It seems you don't have problems with implementation, just with logic

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to split a string in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java)

Comment: Will the streetNo always consist of a single word (i.e., some bunch of characters not containing any spaces) and will it always appear at the end of the address? It's fairly easy if both of those conditions are true, possibly a lot more difficult if not.

Comment: @Kevin Yes both conditions are true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split it by the first number in `String` and trim the space at the end of `streetName`. If you wouldn't trim the string, then the result would be `"Piazza Victoria "`.

```
String str = "Piazza Victoria 3425";
String[] part = str.split("(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)");
String streetName = part[0].trim();
int streetNo = Integer.parseInt(part[1]);
```

EDIT:

If the `streetNo` doesn't have to be number, then split it by spaces and build the `streetName`.

```
String[] part = str.split(" ");
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(part[0]);
for(int i = 1; i < part.length-1; i++) {
    sb.append(" ").append(part[i]);
}
String streetName = sb.toString();
String streetNo = part[part.length-1];
```

Comment: according to the comments, the number can contain non-numerical chars. so why not just string split with space as regex, the last element is the number, and concatenate the rest to the street?

Comment: @AP11 Instead of int streetNo = Integer.parseInt(part[1]) can I do that String streetNo = part[1]?

Comment: @elvis of course, you can. I didn't know whether you want to use it as number or as text

Answer (score -1):

There is a way to split the address by space. check the link below for more info

```
str = "Hello, This is a String";
String[] splited = str.split("\\s+");
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7899558/7904389

But the good practice is to save the address as street name, street number in different field so that you can get it later.

Comment: don't just post a link as an answer, post an actual answer, you might add the link as "additional info", and, saving it in different fields is the actual goal here. If you just want to answer it by the answer of that so question, you should have flagged it as a duplicate

Comment: Thank you ! I didn't aware of it.

Answer (score -1):

It seems you want to split a string into text and digits. You'll need to pass in a regex to the String.split() method in Java to efficiently do this.

```
String[] parts = "Piazza Victoria 123".split("(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)");
String streetName = parts[0].trim();
String streetNo = parts[1];
```

You can check out this link to find out more
[Need to split a string into two parts in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2995606/need-to-split-a-string-into-two-parts-in-java).

I hope it is helpful

Comment: why not provide an example here? if you just wanted to point to that so answer, you should flag it as a duplicate

Comment: @Stultuske This user cannot flag questions

Comment: @dreamcrash problem is, by writing answers that get downvoted, it 'll take even longer before they can.

Comment: @Stultuske Yep, I agree with that, I am just saying that even if e.unix wanted e.unix cannot do it xD

Comment: Okay then @Stultuske. I'll edit my answer