# How can I get the last integer "56" from String like ra12ke43sh56?

Tags: java

How can I get the last integer "56" from String like ra12ke43sh56?

I have to modify the next value as ra12ke43sh57 so I want to get the last the integer value.

Answer (score 28):

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = str.length() - 1; i >= 0; i --) {
    char c = str.charAt(i);
    if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
        sb.insert(0, c);
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
String result = sb.toString();
```

or

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[0-9]+$");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
if(m.find()) {
    result = m.group();
}
```

And then `Integer.parseInt(result)`

Comment: Why not just pin the RE to the end with '[0-9]+$'?

Comment: Thanks but it will work for last digit abc88 but when it comes abc9999 it won't work

Comment: @nicerobot - indeed, I updated my answer
@Rakesh - I didn't get your comment. It works with abc9999 as well.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps something like this is what you want ([see also on ideone.com](http://www.ideone.com/Ck2sv)):

```
static String nextId(String id) {
    String[] parts = id.split("(?=\\d+$)", 2);
    final int L = parts[1].length();
    final int num = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]) + 1;
    return parts[0] + String.format("%0"+L+"d", num);
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] tests = {
        "jamesBond007", "ra12ke43sh57", "-42", "x888y999", "00000"
    };
    for (String test : tests) {
        System.out.println(nextId(test));
    }
    // prints "jamesBond008", "ra12ke43sh58", "-43", "x888y1000", "00001"
}
```

---

#### How it works

There are several things at work here:

- Using [`String.split(String regex, int limit)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29), limited to 2 parts

  - `parts[0]` is the static prefix, possibly empty
  - `parts[1]` is the sequence of digits at the end of the string
- Using zero-width matching positive lookahead to split

  - `(?=\d+$)` matches a position where you can match `\d+$`

    - That is, digit character `\d` character class
    - ... repeated one-or-more times `+`
    - ... till the end of the string anchor `$`
- Using [`String.format`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) to preserve any leading zeroes

  - A format like `%05d` means:

    - `0` : pad with leading zeroes
    - `5` : width is 5
    - `d` : decimal integer conversion

#### Related questions

On lookarounds:

- [How does the regular expression `(?<=#)[^#]+(?=#)` work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3092797/how-does-the-regular-expression-work/)
- [Java split is eating my characters.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2819933/java-split-is-eating-my-characters)

#### References

- [regular-expressions.info/Lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), [Character Classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), [Repetition](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html), [Anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html)

Comment: You're obviously in love with lookarounds :) but in this case the simple "(\\d+)$" would do too - just capture the id directly, instead of matching the start position of the id and splitting the string there.

Answer (score 4):

Not an answer, just to mention that the "obvious" regular expressions for this (as posted above) have a nasty quadratic behavior in the worst case (I'm pretty sure you are not dealing with such degenerate cases though, but it's interesting in its own accord).

Here is a little graph I prepared:
[alt text http://img517.imageshack.us/img517/1158/imageerp.jpg](http://img517.imageshack.us/img517/1158/imageerp.jpg)

I used strings of the form "111..1111a2"
There are `J` occurrences of '1'.

The reason of the bad performance is obvious: the matcher keeps seeing 1s and happily thinks it's going to succeed, and only when it finds `a` nearly the end it finds that `a` doesn't match `$`, so it goes all the way back, and starts at the second character.

Initially I thought that possessive quantifiers would help here, but it doesn't look straight-forward. Even if I write `\d++`, if I call matcher.find() it will still try to match the pattern *starting from every index* anyway, i.e. the outer loop takes no hint from the previous fails of possesive quantifiers. (Note this issue does not affect Matcher.matches() since that only tries to match at a single index, the start).

In this particular problem, to avoid this behavior we would have to reverse the string and search with a simple `^\\d+` pattern, or iterate the characters backwards and do a manual match.

Comment: This is another instance of Schlemiel the Painter's algorithm, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schlemiel_the_Painter%27s_algorithm, coined by our very own Joel Spolsky.

Answer (score 3):

```
String result = str.substring(str.replaceAll("[0-9]+$","").length());
```

Breaking this down, if `str` is `ra12ke43sh56`:

```
str.replaceAll("[0-9]+$","")
```

returns all but the last set of digits, i.e. ra12ke43sh

`substring` of the length of this on the main string returns just the ending digits, i.e. 56.

Answer (score 1):

```
  public static String getLastDigits(String string) {
    String reverseTaskId = new StringBuilder(string).reverse().toString();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < reverseTaskId.length(); i++) {
        if (Character.isDigit(reverseTaskId.charAt(i))) {
            sb.insert(i, reverseTaskId.charAt(i));
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    return sb.reverse().toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class PrefixId {

    public String getTransactionNumber() {

    String prevNumber = "123abc321";
    String incredNumber = "";
    for (int i = prevNumber.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        char ch = prevNumber.charAt(i);

        if (incredNumber.length() > 0 && !Character.isDigit(ch)) {
            break;
        } else if (Character.isDigit(ch)) {
            incredNumber = incredNumber + ch;
        }

    }
    if (incredNumber.length() > 0) {
        incredNumber = new StringBuffer(incredNumber).reverse().toString();
        prevNumber = prevNumber.replace(incredNumber, ""
                + (Long.parseLong(incredNumber) + 1));
    }
    return prevNumber;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    PrefixId prefixId = new PrefixId();
    System.out.println(prefixId.getTransactionNumber());

}
```

}