# How does the regular expression ‘(?<=#)[^#]+(?=#)’ work?

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, lookbehind

I have the following regex in a C# program, and have difficulties understanding it:

```
(?<=#)[^#]+(?=#)
```

I'll break it down to what I think I understood:

```
(?<=#)    a group, matching a hash. what's `?<=`?
[^#]+     one or more non-hashes (used to achieve non-greediness)
(?=#)     another group, matching a hash. what's the `?=`?
```

So the problem I have is the `?<=` and `?<` part. From reading MSDN, `?<name>` is used for naming groups, but in this case the angle bracket is never closed.

I couldn't find `?=` in the docs, and searching for it is really difficult, because search engines will mostly ignore those special chars.

Comment: Check this for an explanation on lookaround http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973436/regex-lookahead-lookbehind-and-atomic-groups/2973609#2973609

Answer (score 36, accepted):

They are called lookarounds; they allow you to assert if a pattern matches or not, without actually making the match. There are 4 basic lookarounds:

- Positive lookarounds: see if we CAN match the `pattern`...

  - `(?=pattern)` - ... to the *right* of current position (look *ahead*)
  - `(?<=pattern)` - ... to the *left* of current position (look *behind*)
- Negative lookarounds - see if we can NOT match the `pattern`

  - `(?!pattern)` - ... to the *right*
  - `(?<!pattern)` - ... to the *left*

As an easy reminder, for a lookaround:

- `=` is *positive*, `!` is *negative*
- `<` is look *behind*, otherwise it's look *ahead*

#### References

- [regular-expressions.info/Lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

---

#### But why use lookarounds?

One might argue that lookarounds in the pattern above aren't necessary, and `#([^#]+)#` will do the job just fine (extracting the string captured by `\1` to get the non-`#`).

Not quite. The difference is that since a lookaround doesn't *match* the `#`, it can be "used" again by the next attempt to find a match. Simplistically speaking, lookarounds allow "matches" to overlap.

Consider the following input string:

```
and #one# and #two# and #three#four#
```

Now, `#([a-z]+)#` will give the following matches ([as seen on rubular.com](http://www.rubular.com/r/MeMvKRkBcb)):

```
and #one# and #two# and #three#four#
    \___/     \___/     \_____/
```

Compare this with `(?<=#)[a-z]+(?=#)`, which matches:

```
and #one# and #two# and #three#four#
     \_/       \_/       \___/ \__/
```

Unfortunately this can't be demonstrated on rubular.com, since it doesn't support lookbehind. However, it does support lookahead, so we can do something similar with `#([a-z]+)(?=#)`, which matches ([as seen on rubular.com](http://www.rubular.com/r/y2pyZjEvg5)):

```
and #one# and #two# and #three#four#
    \__/      \__/      \____/\___/
```

#### References

- [regular-expressions.info/Flavor Comparison](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html)

Answer (score 4):

As another poster mentioned, these are **[lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)**, special constructs for changing what gets matched and when. This says:

```
(?<=#)    match but don't capture, the string `#`
            when followed by the next expression

[^#]+     one or more characters that are not `#`, and

(?=#)     match but don't capture, the string `#`
            when preceded by the last expression
```

So this will match all the characters in between two `#`s.

Lookaheads and lookbehinds are very useful in many cases. Consider, for example, the rule "match all `b`s not followed by an `a`." Your first attempt might be something like `b[^a]`, but that's not right: this will also match the `bu` in `bus` or the `bo` in `boy`, but you only wanted the `b`. And it won't match the `b` in `cab`, even though that's not followed by an `a`, because there are no more characters to match.

To do that correctly, you need a lookahead: `b(?!a)`. This says "match a `b` but don't match an `a` afterwards, and don't make that part of the match". Thus it'll match just the `b` in `bolo`, which is what you want; likewise it'll match the `b` in `cab`.

Comment: You said: `b(?!a)` - "This says 'match a `b` followed by something that is not an `a`'" -- I think that's misleading, actually. It says "match a `b`, after which you can't match an `a`." In particular, `b` doesn't really have to be followed by anything; it most definitely doesn't have to be followed by `[^a]`. It can be at the end of the string. That's where `b(?!a)` and `b(?=[^a])` differ.

Comment: You're right, that wasn't the best wording. I'll edit to clarify.