# Java split CSV with two patterns

Tags: java, parsing, csv, export-to-csv

I have this CSV with this format, I need to split in 16 Parts, according with the text's:

```
"MY TEXT","EVER, OK",,,,,,,,,,"The, CARLO","DO","ALFA","OME, GA",,
```

I have this way, but when appear case's with commas inside "OME, GA" doesn't work.

```
String[] lineToMap = line.split(",");
```

How I can control this cases?

Solution

I discovered this library: OPEN CSV, in my Test's work very well, but I have a problem with the codification (strange symbols like � instead ü), with characters like ü, ö, etc.. I'm using languages like German and French. I was testing with UTF-8 but didn't work, Any idea to fix this?

```
CSVReader reader=new CSVReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("data/test.csv"), "UTF-8"), 
                ',', '"', 0);
         //Read CSV line by line and use the string array as you want
          String[] nextLine;
          try {
            while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
                 if (nextLine != null) {
                    for (String element : nextLine) {
                        System.out.println(element);
                    }                   
                 }
               }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Why are you splitting it and not using CSV reader ?

Comment: Grab every item inside the quotation marks.

Comment: yes but this line represents 16 parts, even the empty parts, like ,,,,,, = empty part, but I need to take it any way

Comment: I believe read next will give you null if it is empty. will still keep your ordering.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3568995/how-do-i-match-a-pattern-with-optional-surrounding-quotes

Comment: I discovered the library Open CSV, works well but I have problems with special character's like ü = �, Any Idea?

Answer (score -3):

Trying splitting on `","` instead and handle the edge cases at the beginning and end of the arrays by hand.

Comment: wont work if there are numeric values like 2,4,5,"ok","will work now"

Comment: Well, I hope your CSV isn't mixed :) It won't work on  `,,,,,,,` either, but it gets him a lot farther.

Comment: no that is not the case his offsets will be messed up.