# RexEx to match a RegEx with a mixture of permutations and choices

Tags: regex, permutation, mixing

I want to check if my students get the RegEx to that Question right:

> We want to have a number from 1 to 6 and afterwords a letter from a to d which could be written small or big. So things like 1d, 2A, 4b, ...

The RegEx I want to have from my students should be something like `[1-6][a-dA-D]` or `[123456][abcdABCD]` or mixtures of these two and all permutations of the second ones.

In my researches I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3101366/regex-to-match-1234-1324-2341-all-permutations-of-1-2-3-4#new-answer?newreg=66d57af22b4e4a72b39b4ad1a85ff67e) for the permutations:

```
^(?:([1-4])(?!.*\1)){4}$
```

and it works by it's own (as well without the `^$`) but when I combine it with a choices operator (`|`) it allows as well repetitions like `[111111][a-dA-D]` and that's not what I want to have.

That's what I try out until yet:

```
[\[]((?:([1-6])(?!.*\1)){6}|[1]\-[6])[\]][\[]((?:([a-dA-D])(?!.*\1)){8}|([a][\-][d][A][\-][D]|[A][\-][D][a][\-][d]))[\]]
```

Testdata:

```
[1-6][A-Da-d]
[123456][a-dA-D] 
[654321][AaBbCcDd]  
[241365][abcdABCD]
```

Comment: Can you make your question more expressive, add some sample examples and test data against which you want to run Regex?

Comment: This seems like a bad way of validating their answers. It will be easier and clearer to just validate the answer against a set of test cases.

Comment: Either validate it against a set of test cases, or parse the regex pattern yourself to validate it - the assignment is simple so this kind of validation should be straightforward. Checking permutations isn't really a good fit for regex.

Comment: There is, except of my ideas, no test data jet. the problem is, that it is a moodle online class, which I construct for a course at my university (for using later in real life). In that formula it's only possible to enter 4 answers which are all clear text or RegEx. One I need to check all the wrong cases I have no other Idea than a RegEx for that one, so there are only three cases where I can check the right answers. I first didn't thought about the permutations but I'm afraid that my Prof checks these cases and than I'm in trouble... :/

Comment: Depends also on the flavor of regex...which parser is being used?

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I decided to tell them, that they have to write the answer in the correct alphabetic and numeric order and the small letters first.Like that the problem is gone. :)

Answer (score 0):

In order to validate `regex` I will suggest to run some unit tests to them validating what you are expecting to... at the minimum I'll have:

- A test that validates that it is a valid Regular Expression. Compiling it.
- A test that validates it matches a simple use case. `1A`, `1B`
- Tests that validates against invalid use cases like `A1`, `B1`, `^d`, `88D`