# regexp - find numbers in a string in any order

Tags: regex, r

I need to find a regexp that allows me to find strings in which i have all the required numbers but only once.

For example:

```
a <- c("12","13","112","123","113","1123","23","212","223","213","2123","312","323","313","3123","1223","1213","12123","2313","23123","13123")
```

I want to get:

```
"123" "213" "312"
```

The pattern 123 only once and in any order and in any position of the string

I tried a lot of things and this seemed to be the closer while it's still very far from what I want :

```
grep('[1:3][1:3][1:3]', a, value=TRUE)
[1] "113"   "313"   "2313"  "13123"
```

Comment: With POSIX regex, you can only specify all the permutations.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3101366/regex-to-match-1234-1324-2341-all-permutations-of-1-2-3-4/3102205#3102205 (actually a duplicate, but if you use pcre regex)

Comment: I think a simpler regex can do the job: `grep('^[123]{3}$', a, value=TRUE)` - that will find all 3 digit numbers containing `1`, `2` or `3` digits.

Comment: `grep('^(?!.*(.).*\1)[123]{3}', a, value=TRUE, perl=T)`

Comment: I am getting pretty close thanks for your quick responses. What i exactly need is to find all 3 digit numbers containing 1 2 AND 3 digits

Comment: Then I think my answer fits your requirements best. Posted as an answer with explanations.

Comment: think he don't want to allow duplicate digits..

Comment: Theo do you mean this https://regex101.com/r/sV2gI6/1

Comment: @AvinashRaj 's code works if you add a second backslash `\\1`

Comment: @PierreLafortune ya, forget that.. can't edit the comment after 5 mins :(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> What i exactly need is to find all 3 digit numbers containing 1 2 AND 3 digits

Then you can safely use

```
grep('^[123]{3}$', a, value=TRUE)
##=> [1] "112" "123" "113" "212" "223" "213" "312" "323" "313"
```

The regex matches:

- `^` - start of string
- `[123]{3}` - Exactly 3 characters that are either `1`, or `2` or `3`
- `$` - assert the position at the end of string.

Also, if you only need unique values, use [`unique`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/unique.html).

If you do not need to allow *the same digit more than once*, you need a Perl-based regex:

```
grep('^(?!.*(.).*\\1)[123]{3}$', a, value=TRUE, perl=T)
## => [1] "123" "213" "312"
```

Note the double escaped back-reference. The `(?!.*(.).*\\1)` negative look-ahead will check if the string has no repeated symbols with the help of a capturing group `(.)` and a back-reference that forces the same captured text to appear in the string. If the same characters are found, there will be no match. See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/aKMnNf).

The `(?!.*(.).*\\1)` is a [negative look-ahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#negative). It only asserts the absence of some pattern *after* the current regex engine position, i.e. it checks and returns true if there is no match, otherwise it returns false. Thus, it does not not "consume" characters, it does not "match" the pattern inside the look-ahead, the regex engine stays at the same location in the input string. In this regex, it is the beginning of string (`^`). So, right at the beginning of the string, the regex engine starts looking for `.*` (any character but a newline, 0 or more repetitions), then captures 1 character `(.)` into group 1, again matches 0 or more characters with `.*`, and then tries to match the same text inside group 1 with `\\1`. Thus, if there is `121`, there will be no match since the look-ahead will return *false* as it will find two `1`s.

Comment: Thanks a lot the last one works perfectly fine with my problem. As i'm quite new in regex what does the     (?!.*(.).*\\1)     mean

Comment: I have added an expanded explanation about what the negative look-ahead anchored at the start is doing with the input string. Note that `.` can be used in the look-ahead without any risk since what we really *match* (i.e. consume and keep in the match value) is either `1` or `2` or `3`.

Answer (score 1):

you can as well use this

```
grep('^([123])((?!\\1)\\d)(?!\\2|\\1)\\d', a, value=TRUE, perl=T)
```

see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/sV2gI6/5)

Comment: It matches [`311`](https://regex101.com/r/tD4zD0/1) because you only check if the 2nd and 3rd digits are not the same as the 1st digit.

Comment: The only trouble there is with it is it's difficult to scale. For some SO "gurus", it is a serious drawback (I was downvoted for such suggestions in the past).

Comment: Thanks. +1 for your answer