# Exclude only 0 in regular expression javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to create a regular expression which will take one to ten numeric value but it should not accept if only 0's are provided

for example

```
1 is valid input
1111123455 is valid input
01 is valid input
010 is valid input
0000 is not valid input
0 is also not valid input
0000000000 is also not valid input
```

i tried regex

```
^([0-9]{1,10}|)$
```

which accepts ten numeric but how to avoid only 0's

Comment: Do you mean `[1-9]`?

Comment: it should also accept 0 but not only 0's like 100 is valid

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7036324/what-is-the-regex-for-any-positive-integer-excluding-0

Comment: `^[1-9][0-9]{,9}$` ?

Comment: Can't you just check for Number(input) === 0?

Comment: @DenysSéguret 0005 is also valid

Comment: So, is `0123` valid? or is only `1230` valid - can you _start_ with zero or is it a positive number? EDIT: answered just as I was commenting.

Comment: @this.lau_  i dont want to call function or validate otherwise if it could be done with with regex

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You may use a negative lookahead:

```
^(?!0+$)[0-9]{1,10}$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jM7hR2/2)

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!0+$)`  - no just zeros are allowed up to the end of string
- `[0-9]{1,10}` - 1 to 10 digits
- `$` - end of string.

**NOTE**: To also allow empty value, use `0` as the min argument in the limiting quantifier:

```
^(?!0+$)[0-9]{0,10}$
              ^
```

See [How Negative Lookahead Works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31201690/find-word-not-followed-by/31201710#31201710) ([more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32886477/regexp-find-numbers-in-a-string-in-any-order/32886855#32886855)) to learn more about how `(?!0+)` works in this pattern. In short: right at the start of the string, we check the whole string for just zeros. If there is a zero or more right after start of a string, the match is failed. Else, 1 (or 0) to 10 digits are matched and the result is returned.

Comment: thanks @Wiktor this one is working if u can concept of negative lokahead it would be helpul thanks again

Comment: I am just not sure why an empty alternative is used in the OP regex - `^([0-9]{1,10}|)$`. It may match an empty string.

Comment: it is also required if field is left empty then error should not be shown not important  here

Comment: The `[0-9]` can be simplified to just `\d`.

Comment: @ruohola Yes, in JS, it can. However, in other regex flavors, like Python 3 `re` or .NET, `\d` will match all Unicode digits, and that is not what is expected in most cases. `\d` does not work across all regex flavors, e.g. POSIX. Thus, it is a good idea to keep to the character class solution, which is most portable.

Answer (score 2):

You can check this with Number function like this.No need of regex.

```
var str = '10001';
console.log(Boolean(Number(str))); This returns true if string does not contain only zeros and false if string contains only zeros
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex as :`^(?=.*[1-9])\d{1,10}$`

[Explaination](https://regex101.com/r/mE4iA9/1) :

> `^` assert position at start of the string
>
> `(?=.*[1-9])` Positive Lookahead - Assert that the regex below can be
>   matched .* matches any character (except newline)   Quantifier: *
>   Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving
>   back as needed [greedy]
>
> [1-9] match a single character present in the list below    1-9 a
>   single character in the range between 1 and 9
>
> `\d{1,10}` match a digit [0-9]   Quantifier: {1,10} Between 1 and 10
>   times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
>
> `$` assert position at end of the string

```js
console.log("1".match(/^(?=.*[1-9])\d{1,10}$/));
console.log("1111123455".match(/^(?=.*[1-9])\d{1,10}$/));
console.log("0000".match(/^(?=.*[1-9])\d{1,10}$/));
console.log("0".match(/^(?=.*[1-9])\d{1,10}$/));
console.log("0000000000".match(/^(?=.*[1-9])\d{1,10}$/));
```