# Remove leading Zeros from Decimal String

Tags: java, regex

I want to remove leading 0s from my decimal string.

I'm using right now below code snippet.

```
inp.replaceAll("^0*","")
```

Its working fine until am getting `0.00`. Becasue if `0.00`, Its giving me `.00` as output, which is not correct ..!

Can anyone share how it can achieved using regex ?

Comment: The `0.` at the start of `0.00` is not matched with `^0+(?!\.0+$)` because `(?!\.0+$)` does not allow matching `0` that is followed with `.` and 1 or more zeros. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56457560/3832970). I explained every part of the regex.

Comment: If you have trouble understanding how negative lookahead works, please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31201710/3832970) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32886477/regexp-find-numbers-in-a-string-in-any-order/32886855#32886855), my former answers where I explained their workings in detail.

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
s = s.replaceAll("^0+(?!\\.0+$)", "");
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/u0mGh9/3) and the [regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E0%2B(%3F!%5C.0%2B%24)):

[image]

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `0+` - one or more `0` digits
- `(?!\\.0+$)` - not immediately followed with `.` and 1+ zeros  up to the end of the string.

Comment: it’s not working...If I use 00.7700 it’s showing .7700...Not correct ....!

Comment: @Elena Then use `"^0+(?!\\.)"` or `"^0+(?=[^.])"`. Could you please collect your test cases and add them to the question? It will be easier to give you the definitive answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Test
public void testStripLeadingZero() {
    List<String> tests = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(
            "0.05",
            "-0.03",
            "100.03",
            "-100.03",
            "000010",
            "-00020",
            "0077.778",
            "-0088.888"
    ));
    for (String s : tests) {
        String result = s.replaceFirst("^0+", "").replaceFirst("^-0+", "-");
        System.err.println("result: " + result);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
result: .05
result: -.03
result: 100.03
result: -100.03
result: 10
result: -20
result: 77.778
result: -88.888
```